# Padding zero in the last digit

Tags: java, excel

How to add a **zero** in the last digit of excel file ?

I print below value by code below

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00"); 
System.out.println(s.getNetAmount());
System.out.println(df.format(s.getNetAmount()));
```

and the result was

```
691.200
691.20
```

But when I write it into excel file, I expect to get **691.20**, but I get 691.2.

This is how I write to excel file

```
      public void write(List<? extends List> list) throws Exception {

            if (list != null) {
                try {
                    writeFile(header(), detail(list.get(0)));
                } catch (BatchRunException ex) {
                    throw new BatchRunException(" Fail..." + ex);
                }
            }
        }

 private void writeFile(String header, List<String> detail) throws IOException, BatchRunException {

        String fullPath = outputPath + fileNameFormat;

        File file = new File(fullPath);
        File path = new File(outputPath);

        if (!path.exists()) {
            path.mkdirs();
        }

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
            bw.write(header);
            bw.write(NEW_LINE);

            for (String s : detail) {

                bw.write(s);
                bw.write(NEW_LINE);
            }


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new BatchRunException(" Fail..." + ex);
        }
    }

    private String header() {
        StringBuilder bf = new StringBuilder();

        bf.append("Employee Name").append(SEPERATOR);
        bf.append("Amount").append(SEPERATOR);
        return bf.toString();
    }

    private List<String> detail(List<SettlementList> dList) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList();
        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("0");

        for (SettlementList s : dList) {
            StringBuilder bf = new StringBuilder();

            bf.append(s.Name()).append(SEPERATOR);
            bf.append(s.getNetAmount()).append(SEPERATOR); // here the error
            list.add(bf.toString());    
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: because of excels cell formatting

Comment: Excel uses binary representation of decimal values, similar to Java's `double`. But you could add numeric format to the cell.

Comment: @PhilippSander how can I get rid of the cell formatting ?

Comment: Do not get rid of, set yourself...

Comment: @AI. you shouldn't get rid of it, you should select number/currency formatting

Comment: How are you writing it to an Excel file?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack post updated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep decimal places when open CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771112/keep-decimal-places-when-open-csv)

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I want it display 691.20 instead of 691.2. The link you gave not what I want...

Comment: The program will be run by someone else, but not in my PC....

Comment: Your problem is that you're generating a CSV-like file not a Excel file, hence the link. There is no way to pre-format your data in a CSV file. You will have to use a proper Excel file format writing library, as implied by @Darshan Mehta's presumptive answer

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack can I just format a specific cell ?

Comment: I advise you to research the difference between CSV and the various Excel formats. Then you'll understand why the answer is no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of `Cell` style and not `DecimalFormat`. Try setting the cell style, e.g.:

```
HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("0.00"));
cell.setCellValue(s.getNetAmount().doubleValue());
```

**Update**

It looks like you are writing into `csv` file and trying to open it with xls. In this case, Excel will format the cells based on the data. So, for rows with values like `691.200`, Excel will interpret these as numeric values and format it accordingly (making it `691.2`). There are two ways to solve it:

1. Write to `xls` instead of `csv` with Apache POI library (here is an example) and apply the cell format as per the code snippet above
2. Write to csv with these numbers as `Strings`, open it in excel and apply `Text` formatting for corresponding columns.

Comment: the s.getNetAmount is  BigDecimal

Comment: These are just the example names, can you share the code that writes to xls? I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @DarshanMehta you need to explain that the OP needs to use HSSF library to achieve what they want

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack can I just format a specific cell

Comment: @AI. have a look at the update and explanation above

Answer (score 0):

[image: format your cell with this configuration]

select your cell and right click on it , then click on format cell and do this configuration then clik ok

Comment: The program will be run by someone else, not in my PC.