# How to automatically change e-mail view from text to html in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

In Outlook, my e-mails are displayed as plain text due to e-mail security gorup policies. I have to activate html view via the menu above the mail content each time when I open the e-mail.

Is there a simple VBA code that automatically changes the view from text to html, when opening the e-mail?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a selection of emails from RichText to HTML Format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708291/how-can-i-convert-a-selection-of-emails-from-richtext-to-html-format)

Answer (score 0):

The [MailItem.BodyFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.bodyformat) property returns or sets an `OlBodyFormat` constant indicating the format of the body text.

```
'Set body format to HTML  
MailItem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Unfortunately I don't experience to create the specific function that triggers the format change. The linked example is only for new e-mails. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe we are talking about *viewing* messages, not creating messages.

What about when `MailItem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML` doesn't work?

Our IT sets previews and message views to Plain Text, but allows selecting "*We converted this message into plain text*" and clicking "*Display as HTML*".