# Outlook VBA to format text as HTML , and select a quick parts

Tags: vba, outlook

I am completely clueless about VBA for outlook.  I was hoping that I could record macros, but I see that its not possible.

So the issue I am having is that I receive close to 100 emails daily that arrive in plain text, and I always need to convert to  HTML so that I can select a Quick Parts, then send the email.

Can this be automated with VBA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a selection of emails from RichText to HTML Format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708291/how-can-i-convert-a-selection-of-emails-from-richtext-to-html-format)

Answer (score 0):

The [MailItem.BodyFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.bodyformat) property allows setting an [OlBodyFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olbodyformat) constant indicating the format of the body text. For example:

```
Sub CreateHTMLMail() 

 'Creates a new email item and modifies its properties. 

 Dim objMail As MailItem 



 'Create mail item 

 Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 

 With objMail 

 'Set body format to HTML 

 .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 

 .HTMLBody = "<HTML><H2>The body of this message will appear in HTML.</H2><BODY>Type the message text here. </BODY></HTML>" 

 .Display 

 End With 

End Sub
```

To handle incoming emails you may use the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event of the Application class. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.