# Exchange users FreeBusy information encompassing recurring appointments

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to get the `FreeBusy` information for a number of outlook exchange users which encompasses their (and my) recurring appointments.

I can get the code to work for ordinary appointments, but am stuck when I also try to ensure that the people are not in a recurring appointment (which does not return with the Free Busy function).

```
Public Sub GetFreeBusyForAPerson()
     Dim usersList As Outlook.AddressEntries
     Dim oEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry
     Dim oContact As Object
     Set usersList = Outlook.Application.Session.AddressLists.Item("All Users").AddressEntries
     Set oEntry=usersList.Item("Jones; Jonathan")
     Debug.Print 
    Mid(oEntry.GetExchangeUser().GetFreeBusy(CDate("08/01/2019"), 60, False), 1, 48)
End Sub
```

I get back `000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`
I know this person has recurring appointments on the day in question, but this is not shown.

Comment: An ordinary appointment is a single, simple entry in your calendar.  A recurring entry is also a single entry but a more complicated entry.  My guess is, `FreeBusy` does not have functionality to analyse a recurring entry and deduce if a recurrence falls within the specified date range.

Comment: Yep, that much I can deduce. Since I do not have any special access to their accounts getting information about their appointments is not, as as I understand it, possible either. so just wondering if there is an approach I have missed?

Comment: I retired 8 years ago and my memory of accessing other people's calendars has faded.  I know we gave each other access to our calendars within teams.  This allowed us to look at individual and combined calendars but I do not remember using VBA on my team's calendars.

Comment: The idea here is to provide a number of time slots where various resources are available and this then can be passed on to an external customer who can then lookup times available for various members of their team so that joint appointments can be made. Currently I setup a dummy appointment and then go to the schedule view and take a snapshot of the days so the customer can see the free slots. What I am trying to do is provide a couple of dates, the time needed, and then have the code define the common free times as a list. There must be a way as outlook can suggest a free time !

Answer (score 2):

I found your question intriguing.  I have no access to `GetExchangeUser().GetFreeBusy` so could not know if you were using the method correctly.  Perhaps someone with relevant knowledge would set you right.  But what if the problem was with `GetFreeBusy`, was there an alternative approach that would give you the functionality you sought.  It is some years since I played with calendar items and I thought it would be interesting to refresh my knowledge.

My recollection is that I have access to my colleagues’ calendars.  But if this is not possible, what alternative is available?  Installing an Outlook macro on multiple systems cannot be automated so I thought I would try Excel.  An Excel workbook containing an Outlook accessing macro could be distributed easily.  Could that macro access the default calendar, extract the information you need and send it to you in an email?  This would not be an ideal solution but if it worked, I believe it would offer an acceptable second best.  If it worked, the code developed within Excel could be distributed as an Outlook macro and linked to a rule that activated the macro when you sent an email with a specific subject.  This would give you almost as much control over the process as you were hoping to have with your current solution.

The key question was: could an Excel macro access all the data within Outlook’s calendar?  Accessing the calendar proved easier than I expected.  However, finding exceptions to recurring items proved tricky since I found the documentation confusing.  However, with careful use of Debug’s Watch to study the contents of an `AppointmentItem` and a recurring `AppointmentItem`’s `RecurringPattern` I was able to discover where the exceptions were stored.

By the time I had completed my investigative macro, Dmitry had stated that `GetFreeBusy` can handle recurring appointments.  Reading his replies to other questions, it is clear that he has considerable expertise so I am inclined to believe him.  He wondered if `CDate("08/01/2019")` was not creating the date you expected.  From your replies this does not seem likely.  You could try. `DateSerial(2019, 1, 8)` which would remove any ambiguity but I doubt that is the problem.

I thought my investigative macro would be helpful.  I have only tested it on my calendar entries so it may require further debugging.  Your `AppointmentItem`s will contain properties that mine do not, so you may need to enhance my macro.

My macro is controlled by three constants:

```
Const DateReportLen As Long = 1            '\ Together identify the length of
Const DateReportLenType As String = "yyyy" '/ the report period
Const DateReportStartOffset As Long = -363 '\ The offset from today to the start of
                                           '| the report period. Set to a positive
                                           '/ value for a date in the future
```

The macro’s report period starts on `Now() + DateReportStartOffset`.  A value of -365 allows be to have a period starting in 1 January 2018.  The two `DateReportLen` constants allow me to set the period end date to a year after the start date.  You will need to adjust these values so you only report on 8 January 2019 or perhaps with a few days either side as well.

The macro creates a file on your desktop named: “Calendar.txt.”  You can change the location and name if you wish.  This file contains every property I consider relevant for every `AppointmentItem` that is within or partially within the report period.  By examining these properties, you may discover your colleague’s calendar is not as you expect.

Note that my macro appears not to work if Outlook is open.  I have not investigated this issue

The macro needs a reference to “Microsoft Outlook nn.n Library” where "nn.n" identifies the version of Office you are using.

The macro which outputs the file need a reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects n.n Library".  “n.n” has been “6.1” for some years.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DiagCal()

  ' Requires reference to Microsoft Outlook nn.n Library
  ' where "nn.n" identifies the version of Office you are using.

  Const DateReportLen As Long = 1            '\ Together identify the length of
  Const DateReportLenType As String = "yyyy" '/ the report period
  Const DateReportStartOffset As Long = -363 '\ The offset from today to the start of
                                             '| the report period. Set to a positive
                                             '/ value for a date in the future

  Dim AppointToReport As New Collection
  Dim AppOutlook As New Outlook.Application
  Dim CalEnt As Object
  Dim CalEntClass As Long
  Dim DateReportEnd As Date
  Dim DateReportStart As Date
  Dim FileBody As String
  Dim FldrCal As Outlook.Folder
  Dim InxAir As Long
  Dim InxFC As Long
  Dim PathDesktop As String

  PathDesktop = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")

  ' Identify date range to be reported on
  DateReportStart = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now) + DateReportStartOffset)
  DateReportEnd = DateAdd(DateReportLenType, DateReportLen, DateReportStart)

  ' This assumes the calendar of interest is the default calendar.
  ' This is almost certainly true.
  Set FldrCal = AppOutlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

  For InxFC = 1 To FldrCal.Items.Count

    Set CalEnt = FldrCal.Items(InxFC)

    ' Occasionally I get syncronisation errors.  This code avoids them.
    CalEntClass = -1
    On Error Resume Next
    CalEntClass = CalEnt.Class
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' I have never found anything but appointments in
    ' Calendar but test just in case
    If CalEntClass = olAppointment Then
      Call DiagCalRecordEntry(CalEnt, DateReportStart, DateReportEnd, AppointToReport)
    End If

  Next InxFC

  FileBody = "Calendar entries within or partially within " & _
             Format(DateReportStart, "d mmm yy") & _
             " to " & Format(DateReportEnd, "d mmm yy") & vbLf & _
             "Total calendar entries: " & FldrCal.Items.Count & vbLf & _
             "Calendar entries within or partially within report period: " & _
             AppointToReport.Count

  For InxAir = 1 To AppointToReport.Count
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & String(70, "=")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & AppointToReport(InxAir)(1)
  Next

  Call PutTextFileUtf8NoBom(PathDesktop & "\Calendar.txt", FileBody)

End Sub
Sub DiagCalRecordEntry(ByRef CalEnt As Object, _
                       ByVal DateReportStart As Date, _
                       ByVal DateReportEnd As Date, _
                       ByRef AppointToReport As Collection, _
                       Optional ByVal OriginalDate As Date)

  ' If calendar entry is within or partially within report range, add
  ' its details to AppointToReport

  Dim AllDayEvent As Boolean
  Dim AppointDtls As String
  Dim AppointId As String
  Dim AppointIdMaster As String
  Dim BusyStatus As String
  Dim DateRecurrEnd As Date
  Dim DateRecurrStart As Date
  Dim DateAppointEnd As Date
  Dim DateAppointStart As Date
  Dim DayOfMonth As Long
  Dim DayOfWeekMask As String
  Dim DayOfWeekMaskCode As Long
  Dim DurationEntry As Long
  Dim DurationRecurr As Long
  Dim InxE As Long
  Dim Instance As Long
  Dim Interval As Long
  Dim Location As String
  Dim MonthOfYear As Long
  Dim NoEndDate As Boolean
  Dim NumOccurrences As Long
  Dim RecurrenceState As String
  Dim RecurrenceType As String
  Dim RecurrPattern As Outlook.RecurrencePattern
  Dim Subject As String
  Dim TimeStart As Date
  Dim TimeEnd As Date

  'Debug.Assert False

  ' Get values from calendar entry which identify if entry is within
  ' report range
  With CalEnt
    DateAppointStart = .Start
    DateAppointEnd = .End
    Select Case .RecurrenceState
      Case olApptNotRecurring
        'Debug.Assert False
        RecurrenceState = "Non-recurring calendar entry"
      Case olApptMaster
        'Debug.Assert False
        RecurrenceState = "Master calendar entry"
      Case olApptException
        'Debug.Assert False
        RecurrenceState = "Exception to Master calendar entry"
      Case olApptOccurrence
        Debug.Assert False
        ' I believe this state can only exist if GetOccurrence() is used
        ' to get a single occurrence of a Master entery. I do not believe
        ' it can appear as a calendar entry
        RecurrenceState = "Occurrence"
      Case Else
        Debug.Assert False
        RecurrenceState = "Unrecognised (" & .RecurrenceState & ")"
    End Select
  End With

  If RecurrenceState = "Master calendar entry" Then
    'Debug.Assert False
    Set RecurrPattern = CalEnt.GetRecurrencePattern()
    With RecurrPattern
      DateRecurrStart = .PatternStartDate
      DateRecurrEnd = .PatternEndDate
    End With
    If DateRecurrStart <= DateReportEnd And _
       DateRecurrEnd >= DateReportStart Then
      ' Some or all occurences of this Master entry are within report range
      'Debug.Assert False
    Else
      ' No occurences of this Master entry are within report range
      'Debug.Assert False
      Exit Sub
    End If
  Else
    ' Non recurring or exception appointment
    If DateAppointStart <= DateReportEnd And _
       DateAppointEnd >= DateReportStart Then
      ' Entry is within report range
      'Debug.Assert False
    Else
      ' Non recurring entry is not within report range
      'Debug.Assert False
      Exit Sub
    End If
  End If

  ' Calendar entry is within or partially within report period

  ' Get remaining properties from entry
  'Debug.Assert False
  With CalEnt
    AllDayEvent = .AllDayEvent
    AppointId = .GlobalAppointmentID
    Select Case .BusyStatus
      Case olBusy
        'Debug.Assert False
        BusyStatus = "Busy"
      Case olFree
        'Debug.Assert False
        BusyStatus = "Free"
      Case olOutOfOffice
       'Debug.Assert False
       BusyStatus = "Out of Office"
      Case olTentative
        Debug.Assert False
        BusyStatus = "Tentative appointment"
      Case olWorkingElsewhere
        'Debug.Assert False
        BusyStatus = "Working elsewhere"
      Case Else
        Debug.Assert False
        BusyStatus = "Not recognised (" & .BusyStatus & ")"
    End Select
    Location = .Location
    Subject = .Subject
  End With

  If RecurrenceState = "Exception to Master calendar entry" Then
    RecurrenceState = RecurrenceState & vbLf & _
                      "Master's Id: " & CalEnt.Parent.GlobalAppointmentID & vbLf & _
                      "Original Date: " & OriginalDate
  End If

  AppointDtls = RecurrenceState & vbLf & _
                "AllDayEvent: " & AllDayEvent & vbLf & _
                "AppointId: " & AppointId & vbLf & _
                "BusyStatus: " & BusyStatus & vbLf & _
                "DateAppointStart: " & DateAppointStart & vbLf & _
                "DateAppointEnd: " & DateAppointEnd & vbLf & _
                "DurationEntry: " & DurationEntry & vbLf & _
                "Location: " & Location & vbLf & _
                "Subject: " & Subject

  If RecurrenceState <> "Master calendar entry" Then
    ' AppointDtls complete for this appointment
    Call StoreSingleAppoint(Format(DateAppointStart, "yyyymmddhhmm"), _
                            AppointDtls, AppointToReport)
  Else
    'Debug.Assert False
    With RecurrPattern
      ' Not all parameters have a meaningful value for all RecurrenceTypes
      ' but the value always appears to be of the correct data type.
      DateRecurrStart = .PatternStartDate
      DateRecurrEnd = .PatternEndDate
      DayOfMonth = .DayOfMonth
      DayOfWeekMaskCode = .DayOfWeekMask
      DayOfWeekMask = ""
      If DayOfWeekMaskCode >= olSaturday Then
        Debug.Assert False
        DayOfWeekMask = "+Saturday"
        DayOfWeekMaskCode = DayOfWeekMaskCode - olSaturday
      End If
      If DayOfWeekMaskCode >= olFriday Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        DayOfWeekMask = "+Friday" & DayOfWeekMask
        DayOfWeekMaskCode = DayOfWeekMaskCode - olFriday
      End If
      If DayOfWeekMaskCode >= olThursday Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        DayOfWeekMask = "+Thursday" & DayOfWeekMask
        DayOfWeekMaskCode = DayOfWeekMaskCode - olThursday
      End If
      If DayOfWeekMaskCode >= olWednesday Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        DayOfWeekMask = "+Wednesday" & DayOfWeekMask
        DayOfWeekMaskCode = DayOfWeekMaskCode - olWednesday
      End If
      If DayOfWeekMaskCode >= olTuesday Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        DayOfWeekMask = "+Tuesday" & DayOfWeekMask
        DayOfWeekMaskCode = DayOfWeekMaskCode - olTuesday
      End If
      If DayOfWeekMaskCode >= olMonday Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        DayOfWeekMask = "+Monday" & DayOfWeekMask
        DayOfWeekMaskCode = DayOfWeekMaskCode - olMonday
      End If
      If DayOfWeekMaskCode >= olSunday Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        DayOfWeekMask = "+Sunday" & DayOfWeekMask
      End If
      If DayOfWeekMask = "" Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        DayOfWeekMask = "None"
      Else
        'Debug.Assert False
        DayOfWeekMask = Mid$(DayOfWeekMask, 2) ' Remove leading +
      End If
      DurationRecurr = .Duration
      Instance = .Instance
      Interval = .Interval
      MonthOfYear = .MonthOfYear
      NoEndDate = .NoEndDate
      NumOccurrences = .Occurrences
      Select Case .RecurrenceType
        Case olRecursDaily
          'Debug.Assert False
          RecurrenceType = "Daily"
        Case olRecursMonthly
          Debug.Assert False
          RecurrenceType = "Monthly"
        Case olRecursMonthNth
          Debug.Assert False
          RecurrenceType = "MonthNth"
        Case olRecursWeekly
          'Debug.Assert False
          RecurrenceType = "Weekly"
        Case olRecursYearly
          'Debug.Assert False
          RecurrenceType = "Yearly"
        Case olRecursYearNth
          Debug.Assert False
          RecurrenceType = "YearNth"
        Case Else
          Debug.Assert False
          RecurrenceType = "Unrecognised Value (" & RecurrenceType & ")"
      End Select
      TimeStart = .StartTime
      TimeEnd = .EndTime
    End With

    AppointDtls = AppointDtls & vbLf & "DateRecurrStart: " & DateRecurrStart _
                              & vbLf & "DateRecurrEnd: " & DateRecurrEnd _
                              & vbLf & "DayOfMonth: " & DayOfMonth _
                              & vbLf & "DayOfWeekMask: " & DayOfWeekMask _
                              & vbLf & "DurationRecurr: " & DurationRecurr _
                              & vbLf & "Instance: " & Instance _
                              & vbLf & "Interval: " & Interval _
                              & vbLf & "MonthOfYear: " & MonthOfYear _
                              & vbLf & "NoEndDate: " & NoEndDate _
                              & vbLf & "NumOccurrences: " & NumOccurrences _
                              & vbLf & "RecurrenceType: " & RecurrenceType _
                              & vbLf & "TimeStart: " & TimeStart & " (" & CDbl(TimeStart) & ")" _
                              & vbLf & "TimeEnd: " & TimeEnd & " (" & CDbl(TimeEnd) & ")"

    For InxE = 1 To RecurrPattern.Exceptions.Count
      AppointDtls = AppointDtls & vbLf & "Exception " & InxE & " for occurrence on " & _
                                   RecurrPattern.Exceptions.Item(InxE).OriginalDate
    Next

    Call StoreSingleAppoint(Format(DateRecurrStart, "yyyymmddhhmm"), _
                            AppointDtls, AppointToReport)

    For InxE = 1 To RecurrPattern.Exceptions.Count
      Call DiagCalRecordEntry(RecurrPattern.Exceptions.Item(InxE).AppointmentItem, _
                              DateReportStart, DateReportEnd, AppointToReport, _
                              RecurrPattern.Exceptions.Item(InxE).OriginalDate)
    Next

  End If ' RecurrenceState <> "Master calendar entry"

End Sub

Public Sub PutTextFileUtf8NoBom(ByVal PathFileName As String, ByVal FileBody As String)

  ' Outputs FileBody as a text file named PathFileName using
  ' UTF-8 encoding without leading BOM

  ' Needs reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects n.n Library"
  ' Addition to original code says version 2.5. Tested with version 6.1.

  '  1Nov16  Copied from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4461250/973283
  '          but replaced literals with parameters.
  ' 15Aug17  Discovered routine was adding an LF to the end of the file.
  '          Added code to discard that LF.
  ' 11Oct17  Posted to StackOverflow
  '  9Aug18  Comment from rellampec suggested removal of adWriteLine from
  '          WriteTest statement would avoid adding LF.
  ' 30Sep18  Amended routine to remove adWriteLine from WriteTest statement
  '          and code to remove LF from file. Successfully tested new version.

  ' References: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4461250/973283
  '             https://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_ref_stream.asp

  Dim BinaryStream As Object
  Dim UTFStream As Object

  Set UTFStream = CreateObject("adodb.stream")

  UTFStream.Type = adTypeText
  UTFStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
  UTFStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
  UTFStream.Open
  UTFStream.WriteText FileBody

  UTFStream.Position = 3 'skip BOM

  Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("adodb.stream")
  BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary
  BinaryStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
  BinaryStream.Open

  UTFStream.CopyTo BinaryStream

  UTFStream.Flush
  UTFStream.Close
  Set UTFStream = Nothing

  BinaryStream.SaveToFile PathFileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
  BinaryStream.Flush
  BinaryStream.Close
  Set BinaryStream = Nothing

End Sub
Sub StoreSingleAppoint(ByVal SeqKey As String, _
                       ByVal AppointDtls As String, _
                       ByRef AppointToReport As Collection)

  ' Entries in AppointToReport are of the form:
  '    VBA.Array(SeqKey, AppointDtls)
  ' Add new entry to AppointToReport so entries are in ascending order by SeqKey

  Dim InxAtr As Long

  If AppointToReport.Count = 0 Then
    'Debug.Assert False
    ' first appointment
    AppointToReport.Add VBA.Array(SeqKey, AppointDtls)
    Else
    For InxAtr = AppointToReport.Count To 1 Step -1
      If SeqKey >= AppointToReport(InxAtr)(0) Then
        ' New appointment belongs after this existing entry
        'Debug.Assert False
        AppointToReport.Add VBA.Array(SeqKey, AppointDtls), , , InxAtr
        Exit Sub
      End If
    Next
    ' If get here, new appointment belongs before all existing appointments
    'Debug.Assert False
    AppointToReport.Add VBA.Array(SeqKey, AppointDtls), , 1
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, have just read through your code and you have really looked into this ! I think this will help, but will need to have some thinking time to get into it. 
I am keen to keep as simple as possible, and will try out the dateserial function to rule out FreeBusy date question on the code I am using. 
I need to use my work computer and connect to the network and exchange server to test out so will have a hack in the next couple of days :-)

Answer (score 0):

GetFreeBusy works just fine with recurring appointments. Are you sure you encode the date correctly? Is "08/01/2019" supposed to be August 1, 2019, or January 8, 2019?
Keep in mind that that the current locale is used for conversion.

Comment: I checked, this is NOT the issue. I have time marked on 08 Jan, 2019, for my colleague at 8:30-9:00, and 11:00-12:00 as "Busy", then I have him tentatively booked between 12:30 and 13:30.
Debugging shows : 
000000000000110002000000 <- Output from FreeBusy
12:00:00 p.m. -> Jonathan BUSY -Tuesday, Jan 8 2019 12:00 p.m.
1:00:00 p.m. -> Jonathan BUSY -Tuesday, Jan 8 2019 01:00 p.m.

- So this clearly shows that thee is some issues with the freebusy function and this is not related to the date I am inputting into the function !

Comment: What is the locale on you machine?

Comment: NZ, tried to enter date as 08/Jan/2019 and still found it did not give back different results 

Comment: I have finally established the root cause of the FreeBusy issue!!!! Turns out that the resource I was targeting had setup working times in his calendar to be from 9am, but also had a private appointment at 8-9 am. FreeBusy does not seem to pick up on this. 
I am not sure if the fact that the appointment is PRIVATE or the fact that the resource working day does not start till 9 is the issue.

Does anyone know :
 a) How to get a resources Start and Finish Time
 b) if FreeBusy is impacted by Private appointments (and if so how to work around this)

Answer (score 0):

FreeBusy will work within the boundaries of the working hours set by the exchange user resources, however it does not seem to work outside of these times. Will continue to investigate and check if I can (a) determine exchange users working times through VBA (though preliminary investigation suggests that I cannot do this), and (b) check when back in work if the function works with private appointments (during each of the users working hours). 
Thanks for all the help, I really do enjoy this site and appreciate the assistance provided!