# Where to find property value "e-mail-account" of mailitem-objects in outlook object-model?

Tags: vba, outlook

The property could not be found analysing all elements of this list (and subobjects):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.actions

Some property-values (like size or body) are directly accessable. 
Other values (like recipients) must be extracted from the stored subobjects. 
But all retrieved values were not corresponding to the visible data in the outlook-column.

- It's not a userproperty.
- The column can be inserted into the outllok e-mail table-view via the fieldlist.

I suppose, that the data stored in the field/column "e-mail-account", was inserted on sending from the property "SendUsingAccount", but this property seems to not be accessible on received emails.

How can this property be accessed/edited in received emails?

[Field Chooser/...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuuaU.png)

[...All Mail Fields/E-Mail account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP5Bq.png)

[Where else to search?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/075sm.png)

Because of this description, I originally thought "SendUsingAccount" might be the data source: "...Returns or sets an Account object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent. Read/write..." 
[But now I know, the string comes from here, when a new account is created (there may be other ways)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIbgk.png)

Comment: If you go to the Outlook VBA Editor and click F2, you will get a list of all the classes.  Scroll down the list on the left until you reach `MailItem`.  On the right will be a list of most of the properties, methods and events for `MailItem`.  You know about `Recipients`.  Different versions of the sender are in `Sender`, `SenderName` and `SenderEmailAddress`.  Is this what you are after?

Comment: `SendUsingAccount` is so an assistant can send an email in the name of their manager.

Comment: @TonyDallimore No. The value seems not to be stored in the sender AddressEntry-Object. I edited my post. Maybe it helps to clarify which value i'm looking for. SendUsingAccount is still the only property i could not access.

Comment: What is the scenario that you are dealing with? What is wrong with the MailItem.SendUsingAccount property? It will be populated on the received message.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I have 55k emails from several accounts on one system without accounts. I have to evaluate them and need to access the value of the field/column "E-Mail account". Every email has this information and it's even preserved after exporting and reimporting from a msg-file. There must be a way to access it ... right?

Comment: Access in what sense? You cannot get any details about that account - take a look at a message with OutlookSpy (click IMessage button): there are two properties - account name and account id. They make no sense outside of the Outlook profile that hosted those accounts.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I used OutlookSpy and the IMessage button. The value I was looking for, was to find in the very first entry of the displayed propertieslist.

IMessage Window:
Property Tag: "0x800D InternetAccountName"
Type: "PT_UNICODE"
Value: (E-Mail-Account-Name of the Account which received the email)

Edit Property Window: 
Tag: PR_EMS_AB_KM_SERVER_W (0x800D001F)

How can I extract this information with vba, if it's not accessible over one of the Mailitem-Object properties?

Comment: You can access that property using MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty() specifying the DASL name displayed by OutlookSpy

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can access that property using MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty() specifying the DASL name displayed by OutlookSpy – Dmitry Streblechenko

MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8580001F")

Comment: Just tried, but got invalid arg...

Answer (score 0):

I do not have “E-Mail Account” in any of my views and I do not wish to change any of them to understand what this column would contain.  I suspect it is not a single property but one that depends on the context.

I do not understand why you expect property "SendUsingAccount" to appear in the received email.  If an assistant sends an email in the name of a manager, I would expect the manager’s name and email address to appear in the sender properties.  I would not expect to find the assistant’s name anywhere.

I use Explorer to investigate emails.  To use Explorer, the user selects one or more emails and then calls a macro that processes the selected emails.  The macros I use for investigations either output a small number of properties to the Immediate Window or every property I have ever been interested in to a desktop file.

I have tidied my routines so I can include both versions without too much duplication.

Note: these routines need references to “Microsoft Scripting Runtime” and "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects n.n Library".  The n.n is probably “6.1” but use whatever version you have.  If you do not understand “references”, ask and I will explain.

Macro `InvestigateEmails` is the macro you call after selecting one or more emails you wish to investigate.  Within the macro is the statement `#Const Selected = True`.  This instructs the macro to call macro `OutSomeProperties` to perform the output.  If you change the statement to `#Const Selected = False` it will call macro `OutAllProperties`.

Macro `OutSomeProperties` outputs a small number of properties to the Immediate Window.

Macro `OutAllProperties` outputs every property that I have ever been interested in.  In particular, it includes the entire message header.  If the value you seek is not in the message header, it is not available to Outlook.

Following these macros are a number of “standard” routines.  I hold these standard routines in their own modules.  I believe I have included ever standard routine called by the first three macros.  If I haven’t, you will get an error message telling you xxxx cannot be found.  Report this error in a comment and I will add the missing routine to to my answer.

Run macro `InvestigateEmails` as is.  Is the value you seek output to the Immediate Window?  If not, amend `InvestigateEmails` to call `OutputAllProperties`.  Look at the text under “PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS”.  Is the value you seek here?  If it is, report the relevant line in a comment and I will help you extract the property you seek.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub InvestigateEmails()

  ' Outputs all or selected properties of one or more emails.

  ' To use:
  '   * Set "Selected" to True or False as required.
  '   * If Selected=True, review OutSomeProperties to ensure it
  '     outputs the properties of interest.
  '   * If Selected=False, review OutAllProperties to ensure it
  '     outputs the properties of interest.
  '   * Select one or more emails from a folder.
  '   * Run this subroutine.

  ' ========================================================================
  ' "Selected = True" to output a small number of properties for
  ' a small number of emails to the Immediate Window.
  ' "Selected = False" to output all properties for any number of emails
  ' to desktop file "InvestigateEmails.txt".
  #Const Selected = True
  ' ========================================================================

  ' Technique for locating desktop from answer by Kyle:
  '                     http://stackoverflow.com/a/17551579/973283
  ' Needs reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"

  Dim Exp As Explorer
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem

  #If Not Selected Then
    Dim FileBody As String
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim Path As String

    Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
  #End If

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  If Exp.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("Please select one or more emails then try again", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  Else
    For Each ItemCrnt In Exp.Selection
      If ItemCrnt.Class = olMail Then
        #If Selected Then
          Call OutSomeProperties(ItemCrnt)
        #Else
          Call OutAllProperties(ItemCrnt, FileBody)
        #End If
      End If
    Next
  End If

  #If Not Selected Then
    Call PutTextFileUtf8NoBom(Path & "\InvestigateEmails.txt", FileBody)
  #End If

End Sub
Sub OutSomeProperties(ItemCrnt As Outlook.MailItem)

  ' Outputs selected properties of a MailItem to the Immediate Window.

  ' The Immediate Window can only display about 200 rows before the older
  ' rows start scrolling off the top.  This means this routine is only
  ' suitable for displaying a small number of simple properties.  Add or
  ' remove properties as necessary to meet the current requirement.

  Dim InxR As Long

  Debug.Print "=============================================="
  Debug.Print "  Profile: " & Session.CurrentProfileName
  Debug.Print "     User: " & Session.CurrentUser
  With ItemCrnt
    Debug.Print "  Created: " & .CreationTime
    Debug.Print " Receiver: " & .ReceivedByName
    Debug.Print " Received: " & .ReceivedTime
    For InxR = 1 To .Recipients.Count
      Debug.Print "Recipient: " & .Recipients(InxR)
    Next
    Debug.Print "   Sender: " & .Sender
    Debug.Print " SenderEA: " & .SenderEmailAddress
    Debug.Print " SenderNm: " & .SenderName
    Debug.Print "   SentOn: " & .SentOn
    Debug.Print "  Subject: " & .Subject
    Debug.Print "       To: " & .To
  End With

End Sub
Sub OutAllProperties(ItemCrnt As Outlook.MailItem, ByRef FileBody As String)

  ' Adds all properties of a MailItem to FileBody.

  ' The phrase "all properties" should more correctly be "all properties
  ' that I know of and have ever been interested in".

  ' Source of PropertyAccessor information:
  '   https://www.slipstick.com/developer/read-mapi-properties-exposed-outlooks-object-model/

  ' 17Apr19  Created by combining a number of earlier routine which output
  '          different sets of properties to a file

  Dim InxA As Long
  Dim InxR As Long
  Dim PropAccess As Outlook.propertyAccessor

  If FileBody <> "" Then
    FileBody = FileBody & String(80, "=") & vbLf
  End If

  With ItemCrnt
    FileBody = FileBody & "From (Sender): " & .Sender
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "From (Sender name): " & .SenderName
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "From (Sender email address): " & _
                                                     .SenderEmailAddress
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "Subject: " & CStr(.Subject)
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "Received: " & Format(.ReceivedTime, "dmmmyy hh:mm:ss")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "To: " & .To
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "CC: " & .CC
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "BCC: " & .BCC
    If .Attachments.Count = 0 Then
      FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "No attachments"
    Else
      FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "Attachments:"
      FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "No.|Type|Path|Filename|DisplayName|"
      For InxR = 1 To .Recipients.Count
        FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "Recipient" & InxR & ": " & .Recipients(InxR)
      Next
      For InxA = 1 To .Attachments.Count
        With .Attachments(InxA)
          FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & InxA & "|"
          Select Case .Type
            Case olByValue
              FileBody = FileBody & "Val"
            Case olEmbeddeditem
              FileBody = FileBody & "Ebd"
            Case olByReference
              FileBody = FileBody & "Ref"
            Case olOLE
              FileBody = FileBody & "OLE"
            Case Else
              FileBody = FileBody & "Unk"
          End Select
          ' Not all types have all properties.  This code handles
          ' those missing properties of which I am aware.  However,
          ' I have never found an attachment of type Reference or OLE.
          ' Additional code may be required for them.
          Select Case .Type
            Case olEmbeddeditem
              FileBody = FileBody & "|"
            Case Else
              FileBody = FileBody & "|" & .Pathname
          End Select
          FileBody = FileBody & "|" & .Filename
          FileBody = FileBody & "|" & .DisplayName & "|"
        End With
      Next
    End If  ' .Attachments.Count = 0
    Call OutLongTextRtn(FileBody, "Text: ", .Body)
    Call OutLongTextRtn(FileBody, "Html: ", .HtmlBody)

    Set PropAccess = .propertyAccessor

    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_RECEIVED_BY_NAME: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0040001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0042001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_REPLY_RECIPIENT_NAMES: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0050001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_EMAIL_ADDRESS: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_RECEIVED_BY_EMAIL_ADDRESS: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0076001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS:" & vbLf & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_SENDER_NAME: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1A001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1F001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_DISPLAY_BCC: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E02001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_DISPLAY_CC: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E03001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_DISPLAY_TO: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E04001E")

    Set PropAccess = Nothing

  End With

End Sub
Sub OutLongTextRtn(ByRef TextOut As String, ByVal Head As String, _
                          ByVal TextIn As String)

  ' * Break TextIn into lines of not more than 100 characters
  '   and append to TextOut.
  ' * The output is arranged so:
  '     xxxx|sssssssssssssss|
  '         |sssssssssssssss|
  '         |ssssssssss|
  '   where "xxxx" is the value of Head and "ssss..." are characters from
  '         TextIn.  The third line in the example could be shorter because:
  '           * it contains the last few characters of TextIn
  '           * there a linefeed in TextIn
  '           * a <xxx> string recording whitespace would have been split
  '             across two lines.

  ' 15Jan19  Added "|" at start and end of lines to make it clearer if
  '          whitespace added by this routine or was in original TextIn
  '  3Feb19  Discovered I had two versions of OutLongText.  Renamed this version to
  '          indicate it returned a formatted string.
  '  4Feb19  Previous version relied on the caller tidying text for display. This
  '          version expects TextIn to be untidied and uses TidyTextForDspl to tidy
  '          the text and then creates TextOut from its output.

  If TextIn = "" Then
    ' Nothing to do
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Const LenLineMax As Long = 100

  Dim PosBrktEnd As Long     ' Last > before PosEnd
  Dim PosBrktStart As Long   ' Last < before PosEnd
  Dim PosNext As Long        ' Start of block to be output after current block
  Dim PosStart As Long       ' First character of TextIn not yet output

  TextIn = TidyTextForDspl(TextIn)
  TextIn = Replace(TextIn, "lf›", "lf›" & vbLf)

  PosStart = 1
  Do While True
    PosNext = InStr(PosStart, TextIn, vbLf)
    If PosNext = 0 Then
      ' No LF in [Remaining] TextIn
      'Debug.Assert False
      PosNext = Len(TextIn) + 1
    End If
    If PosNext - PosStart > LenLineMax Then
      PosNext = PosStart + LenLineMax
    End If
    ' Check for <xxx> being split across lines
    PosBrktStart = InStrRev(TextIn, "‹", PosNext - 1)
    PosBrktEnd = InStrRev(TextIn, "›", PosNext - 1)
    If PosBrktStart < PosStart And PosBrktEnd < PosStart Then
      ' No <xxx> within text to be displayed
      ' No change to PosNext
      'Debug.Assert False
    ElseIf PosBrktStart > 0 And PosBrktEnd > 0 And PosBrktEnd > PosBrktStart Then
      ' Last or only <xxx> totally within text to be displayed
      ' No change to PosNext
      'Debug.Assert False
    ElseIf PosBrktStart > 0 And _
           (PosBrktEnd = 0 Or (PosBrktEnd > 0 And PosBrktEnd < PosBrktStart)) Then
      ' Last or only <xxx> will be split across rows
      'Debug.Assert False
      PosNext = PosBrktStart
    Else
      ' Are there other combinations?
      Debug.Assert False
    End If

    'Debug.Assert Right$(Mid$(TextIn, PosStart, PosNext - PosStart), 1) <> "‹"

    If TextOut <> "" Then
      TextOut = TextOut & vbLf
    End If
    If PosStart = 1 Then
      TextOut = TextOut & Head & "|"
    Else
      TextOut = TextOut & Space(Len(Head)) & "|"
    End If
    TextOut = TextOut & Mid$(TextIn, PosStart, PosNext - PosStart) & "|"
    PosStart = PosNext
    If Mid$(TextIn, PosStart, 1) = vbLf Then
      PosStart = PosStart + 1
    End If
    If PosStart > Len(TextIn) Then
      Exit Do
    End If
  Loop

End Sub
Sub PutTextFileUtf8NoBom(ByVal PathFileName As String, ByVal FileBody As String)

  ' Outputs FileBody as a text file named PathFileName using
  ' UTF-8 encoding without leading BOM

  ' Needs reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects n.n Library"
  ' Addition to original code says version 2.5. Tested with version 6.1.

  '  1Nov16  Copied from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4461250/973283
  '          but replaced literals with parameters.
  ' 15Aug17  Discovered routine was adding an LF to the end of the file.
  '          Added code to discard that LF.
  ' 11Oct17  Posted to StackOverflow
  '  9Aug18  Comment from rellampec suggested removal of adWriteLine from
  '          WriteTest statement would avoid adding LF.
  ' 30Sep18  Amended routine to remove adWriteLine from WriteTest statement
  '          and code to remove LF from file. Successfully tested new version.

  ' References: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4461250/973283
  '             https://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_ref_stream.asp

  Dim BinaryStream As Object
  Dim UTFStream As Object

  Set UTFStream = CreateObject("adodb.stream")

  UTFStream.Type = adTypeText
  UTFStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
  UTFStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
  UTFStream.Open
  UTFStream.WriteText FileBody

  UTFStream.Position = 3 'skip BOM

  Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("adodb.stream")
  BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary
  BinaryStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
  BinaryStream.Open

  UTFStream.CopyTo BinaryStream

  UTFStream.Flush
  UTFStream.Close
  Set UTFStream = Nothing

  BinaryStream.SaveToFile PathFileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
  BinaryStream.Flush
  BinaryStream.Close
  Set BinaryStream = Nothing

End Sub
Function TidyTextForDspl(ByVal Text As String) As String

  ' Tidy Text for dsplay by replacing white space with visible strings:
  '   Leave single space unchanged
  '   Replace single LF by                 ‹lf›
  '   Replace single CR by                 ‹cr›
  '   Replace single TB by                 ‹tb›
  '   Replace single non-break space by    ‹nbs›
  '   Replace single CRLF by               ‹crlf›
  '   Replace multiple spaces by           ‹n s›       where n is number of repeats
  '   Replace multiple LFs by              ‹n lf›      of white space character
  '   Replace multiple CRs by ‹cr› or      ‹n cr›
  '   Replace multiple TBs by              ‹n tb›
  '   Replace multiple non-break spaces by ‹n nbs›
  '   Replace multiple CRLFs by            ‹n crlf›

  ' 15Mar16  Coded
  '  3Feb19  Replaced "{" (\x7B) and "}" (\x7D) by "‹" (\u2039) and "›" (\u203A)
  '          on the grounds that the angle quotation marks were not likely to
  '          appear in text to be displayed.
  '  5Feb19  Add code to treat CRLF as unit
  ' 28Mar19  Code to calculate PosWsChar after "<x>...<x>" converted to "<n x>"
  '          incorrect if "<x>...<x>" at the start of the string.  Unlikely it
  '          was correct in other situations but this did not matter since the
  '          calculated value would be before the next occurrence of "<x>...<x>".
  '          But, if the string was near the beginning of the string, the
  '          calculated value was negative and the code crashed.

  Dim InsStr As String
  Dim InxWsChar As Long
  Dim NumWsChar As Long
  Dim PosWsChar As Long
  Dim RetnVal As String
  Dim WsCharCrnt As Variant
  Dim WsCharValue As Variant
  Dim WsCharDspl As Variant

  WsCharValue = VBA.Array(" ", vbCr & vbLf, vbLf, vbCr, vbTab, Chr(160))
  WsCharDspl = VBA.Array("s", "crlf", "lf", "cr", "tb", "nbs")

  RetnVal = Text

  ' Replace each whitespace individually
  For InxWsChar = 0 To UBound(WsCharValue)
    RetnVal = Replace(RetnVal, WsCharValue(InxWsChar), "‹" & WsCharDspl(InxWsChar) & "›")
  Next

  ' Look for repeats. If found replace <x> by <n x>
  For InxWsChar = 0 To UBound(WsCharValue)
    'Debug.Assert InxWsChar <> 1
    PosWsChar = 1
    Do While True
      InsStr = "‹" & WsCharDspl(InxWsChar) & "›"
      PosWsChar = InStr(PosWsChar, RetnVal, InsStr & InsStr)
      If PosWsChar = 0 Then
        ' No [more] repeats of this <x>
        Exit Do
      End If
      ' Have <x><x>.  Count number of extra <x>x
      NumWsChar = 2
      Do While Mid(RetnVal, PosWsChar + NumWsChar * Len(InsStr), Len(InsStr)) = InsStr
        NumWsChar = NumWsChar + 1
      Loop
      RetnVal = Mid(RetnVal, 1, PosWsChar - 1) & _
                "‹" & NumWsChar & " " & WsCharDspl(InxWsChar) & "›" & _
                Mid(RetnVal, PosWsChar + NumWsChar * Len(InsStr))
      PosWsChar = PosWsChar + Len(InsStr) + Len(NumWsChar)

    Loop
  Next

  ' Restore any single spaces
  RetnVal = Replace(RetnVal, "‹" & WsCharDspl(0) & "›", " ")

  TidyTextForDspl = RetnVal

End Function
```

Comment: @ToniDallimore Thank you for your support and your code. I managed to run your code in "OutAllProperties"-mode. It worked fine, but i could not found the string in the "InvestigateEmails.txt"-file your code created.
It seams to be inserted to the email by Outlook at receive time and means "received via email-account" and not "sended via email-account". It's now stored somewhere in the Outlook-Mailitem, but it was not a part of the sendet email (and message header).

Comment: I understand the confidentiality issues but can you give an idea of what this value is.  If the value is not in the message header then it is not in the incoming message.  Outlook can link emails and deduce information from those links.  Could this be the source?

Comment: @ToniDallimore It now seems sure that it is the name of the downloading account and it is added by Outlook, when receiving emails. It would allow me to determine, which account every email was originally received with.

Comment: Are `To` and `Recipients` different.  The full header includes a history of the addresses through which the message passed.  I do not see how such as value can not be in the message header even if it gets updated elsewhere.

Comment: I have two main email accounts.  If I move an email from one to the other, the original receiver is still identified in the header.  I cannot find a property that has changed as a result of the move.  On your system, can the email address used to download the email from the server be different from the one to which the email is sent?  I am a home user.  If you are a corporate user, you may have functionality I know nothing about and to which I have no access.

Comment: I'm working with a home system right now, with MS-Outlook for 365 MSO 16.0. 

The information is not in the email header. It's a Property called "InternetAccountName".

Outlook writes the name of the receiving email account in there.  

If you copy an email from one account to another, the value will not change.

If you resend a previously received email to an other account, the value is lost and it will be replaced by the name of the new receiving account, on the target system.

Comment: With the support of Dmitry Streblechenko and OutlookSpy http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm (see above), I have now found out how to access the value:  

CurOtlEmlItm.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8580001F")

Some info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/navigation/referencing-properties-by-namespace