# Removing a string that includes CRLF characters from body of e-mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to remove a string from selected incoming MS Outlook (2016) e-mail.

The string is two sentences in German language. I use the **Replace()** function. This principally works. (See my full procedure below.)

The two sentences are sometimes separated by CRLF (Carriage Return, Line Feed) characters, and these are not always at the same place. This seems to be the result of these e-mails passing through various devices before they land in my Outlook inbox.

#### First address the simpler part of the problem

Before addressing the issue of the CRLF appearing on varying places, I want to create a procedure that deals with strings with CRLF at fixed positions.

How the source code of such a string would look:
[image]

(Screen shot history: I saved the e-mail as .html on my harddisk, then opened the .html file in Notepad++, to see the CRLF characters.)

The html tags are not that relevant for me. They can remain in the e-mail. (In fact, the formatting tags vary, too, so it is better to not start tackling them at all.) My only concern is to remove the visible part, i.e. the text "Diese E-Mail kommt... vertrauenswürdig halten".

I tried to catch text with line breaks by including the CR LF part as Chr():

```
strDelete01 = "Diese E-Mail kommt von Personen" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "außerhalb der Stadtverwaltung. Klicken Sie nur auf Links oder Dateianhnge," & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "wenn Sie die Personenn für vertrauenswürdig halten."
```

My procedure does not recognize the string, and accordingly does nothing.

#### My script so far

```
Public Sub EditBodyCgReplace()

'Declarations
   Dim obj As Object
   Dim Sel As Outlook.Selection
   Dim DoSave As Boolean
   Dim NewBody As String
   Dim strDelete01 As String
   Dim strDelete02 As String
   Dim strDelete03 As String
   Dim strDelete04 As String

'Fill the variables 
   strDelete01 = "Diese E-Mail kommt von Personen außerhalb der Stadtverwaltung. Klicken Sie nur auf Links oder Dateianhänge, wenn Sie die Personen für vertrauenswürdig halten."
   strDelete02 = "################################################################################"
   strDelete03 = <hr>
   strDelete04 = "Diese E-Mail kommt von Personen" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "außerhalb der Stadtverwaltung. Klicken Sie nur auf Links oder Dateianhnge," & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "wenn Sie die Personenn für vertrauenswürdig halten."

'Note: I am playing here with various types of strings at once. For example, 
'the procedure will also remove <hr> lines and "#####" strings  

'Work with it 
    If TypeOf Application.ActiveWindow Is Outlook.Inspector Then
        Set obj = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Else
        Set Sel = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If Sel.Count Then
            Set obj = Sel(1)
            DoSave = True
        End If
    End If

    If Not obj Is Nothing Then
        NewBody = Replace(obj.HTMLBody, strDelete01, "")
        NewBody = Replace(obj.HTMLBody, strDelete02, "")
        NewBody = Replace(obj.HTMLBody, strDelete03, "")
        NewBody = Replace(obj.HTMLBody, strDelete04, "")

        If NewBody <> "" Then
            obj.HTMLBody = NewBody
            If DoSave Then
                obj.Save
            End If
        End If
    End If
    End Sub
```

**Question:** What can I do to include the CRLF in the search string?

**Follow-up question**: What can I do to remove such strings with CRLF included in **varying places**? Is there a way to use regular expressions? Can VBA in Outlook deal with it? - Idea: if regular expressions work, perhaps the entire CRLF issue is not an issue anymore, as the expression would look something like

```
"Diese E-Mail kommt von * vertrauenswürdig halten."
```

and thus include anything - including CRLF - in the middle?

#### Perhaps important

After doing various experiments I am starting to feel that MS Outlook does not use HTML at all in its e-mails?

I observe I can practically not address any html code in the obj.HTMLBody. I can address plain text. I cannot address parts of html such as "<hr ", or at least that is what I believe to be observing. (There was a moment when I could address "<hr>" and thus delete it, but I cannot recreate the conditions where this worked yesterday.)

I can save the e-mails ***as*** html files (outside Outlook, somewhere on my harddisk in a separate folder), and in these files I do see the CRLF and other stuff. But perhaps the e-mails, as long as kept in Outlook itself, are stored using some other code?

So what is this code, and how can I address parts of it for deleting?

Comment: I see you have already noticed my full diagnostic tool which I use frequently.  I have now added my Regex solution. I understood from your question that the CRLFs are in different positions in different emails.  This solution will handle moving CRLFs without removing any other CRLFs from the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer your question in parts as I have the spare time.  Someone else may get to the important bit before I do.

I have edited your question.  I did not understand a couple of sentences so I looked at the source and found my suspicion was correct, you had included less than characters.  Stack Overflow permits a limited number of Html tags.  Anything else that looks like an Html tag is ignored.  I replaced each "<" with "&lt;" so readers could see your Html. I can add an explanation if you do not understand why this works.

You have:

```
NewBody = Replace(obj.HTMLBody, strDelete01, "")
NewBody = Replace(obj.HTMLBody, strDelete02, "")
NewBody = Replace(obj.HTMLBody, strDelete03, "")
NewBody = Replace(obj.HTMLBody, strDelete04, "")
If NewBody <> "" Then
```

Each `Replace` (except the first) overwrites the value of `NewBody` created by the previous `Replace`.  You seem to think that if `strDelete04` is not found, NewBody will be empty.  No, if `strDelete04` is not found, `NewBody` will be a copy of `obj.HTMLBody`.

You need something like:

```
NewBody = Replace(obj.HTMLBody, strDelete01, "")
NewBody = Replace(NewBody, strDelete02, "")
NewBody = Replace(NewBody, strDelete03, "")
NewBody = Replace(NewBody, strDelete04, "")
If NewBody <> obj.HTMLBody Then
  ' One or more delete strings found and removed
```

You say that the CRLFs are not in fixed positions.  If so, no simple modification of your code will have the effect you seek.  I will show you how to achieve the effect you seek but first I will have to create some emails containing your text so I can test my code.

**Part 2**

Having looked at your image of the Html more closely, I believe there is a simple solution.  The two CRLFs in the text replace spaces.  Providing this is always what happens, you can use:

```
NewBody = Replace(obj.HTMLBody, vbCr & vbLf, " ")
```

This would remove any CRLF present wherever it appeared within the Html.  It would not matter if there were extra CRLFs because any string of whitespace characters (which includes CR and LF) in an Html document is replaced by a single space when the document is displayed.

You finish the removal of the unwanted text with:

```
Dim strDelete = "Diese E-Mail kommt von Personen außerhalb " & _
                "der Stadtverwaltung. Klicken Sie nur auf " & _
                "Links oder Dateianhänge, wenn Sie die Personen " & _
                "für vertrauenswürdig halten."

NewBody = Replace(NewBody, strDelete, "")
```

If the above does not work, you need a more convenient diagnostic technique.  Saving the entire email as Html may be easy but you cannot be quite sure how the result differs from what a VBA macro would see.  You wonder if Outlook stores emails in a format other than Html.  I cannot imagine why Outlook would convert the incoming SMTP message to some secret format and then convert it back when the user wishes to view it.  If Outlook does have a secret format, it is totally hidden from the VBA programmer.

The following is a simple version of the diagnostic tool I use.  If you need something more advanced, I can provide it but let us try this first.

Copy the code below to an Outlook module.  Select one of these emails and then run macro `DsplHtmlBodyFromSelectedEmails`.  The entire Html body of the email will be output to the Immediate Window in a readable format.  I believe I have included all the subroutines called by the macro.  I apologise in advance if I have not.  If you get a message about an undefined routine, let me know and I will add it to the answer.

```
Sub DsplHtmlBodyFromSelectedEmails()

  ' Select one or emails then run this macro.  For each selected email, the Received Time, the Subject and the Html body are output to the Immediate Window.  Note: the Immediate Window can only display about 200 lines before
The older lines are lost.

  Dim Exp As Explorer
  Dim Html As String
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  If Exp.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("Please select one or more emails then try again", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  Else
    For Each ItemCrnt In Exp.Selection
      With ItemCrnt
        If .Class = olMail Then
          Debug.Print .ReceivedTime & " " & .Subject
          Call OutLongTextRtn(Html, "Html", .HtmlBody)
          Debug.Print Html
        End If
      End With
    Next
  End If

End Sub
Sub OutLongTextRtn(ByRef TextOut As String, ByVal Head As String, _
                          ByVal TextIn As String)

  ' * Break TextIn into lines of not more than 100 characters
  '   and append to TextOut.
  ' * The output is arranged so:
  '     xxxx|sssssssssssssss|
  '         |sssssssssssssss|
  '         |ssssssssss|
  '   where "xxxx" is the value of Head and "ssss..." are characters from
  '         TextIn.  The third line in the example could be shorter because:
  '           * it contains the last few characters of TextIn
  '           * there a linefeed in TextIn
  '           * a <xxx> string recording whitespace would have been split
  '             across two lines.

  If TextIn = "" Then
    ' Nothing to do
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Const LenLineMax As Long = 100

  Dim PosBrktEnd As Long     ' Last > before PosEnd
  Dim PosBrktStart As Long   ' Last < before PosEnd
  Dim PosNext As Long        ' Start of block to be output after current block
  Dim PosStart As Long       ' First character of TextIn not yet output

  TextIn = TidyTextForDspl(TextIn)
  TextIn = Replace(TextIn, "lf›", "lf›" & vbLf)

  PosStart = 1
  Do While True
    PosNext = InStr(PosStart, TextIn, vbLf)
    If PosNext = 0 Then
      ' No LF in [Remaining] TextIn
      'Debug.Assert False
      PosNext = Len(TextIn) + 1
    End If
    If PosNext - PosStart > LenLineMax Then
      PosNext = PosStart + LenLineMax
    End If
    ' Check for <xxx> being split across lines
    PosBrktStart = InStrRev(TextIn, "‹", PosNext - 1)
    PosBrktEnd = InStrRev(TextIn, "›", PosNext - 1)
    If PosBrktStart < PosStart And PosBrktEnd < PosStart Then
      ' No <xxx> within text to be displayed
      ' No change to PosNext
      'Debug.Assert False
    ElseIf PosBrktStart > 0 And PosBrktEnd > 0 And PosBrktEnd > PosBrktStart Then
      ' Last or only <xxx> totally within text to be displayed
      ' No change to PosNext
      'Debug.Assert False
    ElseIf PosBrktStart > 0 And _
           (PosBrktEnd = 0 Or (PosBrktEnd > 0 And PosBrktEnd < PosBrktStart)) Then
      ' Last or only <xxx> will be split across rows
      'Debug.Assert False
      PosNext = PosBrktStart
    Else
      ' Are there other combinations?
      Debug.Assert False
    End If

    'Debug.Assert Right$(Mid$(TextIn, PosStart, PosNext - PosStart), 1) <> "‹"

    If TextOut <> "" Then
      TextOut = TextOut & vbLf
    End If
    If PosStart = 1 Then
      TextOut = TextOut & Head & "|"
    Else
      TextOut = TextOut & Space(Len(Head)) & "|"
    End If
    TextOut = TextOut & Mid$(TextIn, PosStart, PosNext - PosStart) & "|"
    PosStart = PosNext
    If Mid$(TextIn, PosStart, 1) = vbLf Then
      PosStart = PosStart + 1
    End If
    If PosStart > Len(TextIn) Then
      Exit Do
    End If
  Loop

End Sub
Function TidyTextForDspl(ByVal Text As String) As String

  ' Tidy Text for display by replacing white space with visible strings:
  '   Leave single space unchanged
  '   Replace single LF by                 ‹lf›
  '   Replace single CR by                 ‹cr›
  '   Replace single TB by                 ‹tb›
  '   Replace single non-break space by    ‹nbs›
  '   Replace single CRLF by               ‹crlf›
  '   Replace multiple spaces by           ‹n s›       where n is number of repeats
  '   Replace multiple LFs by              ‹n lf›      of white space character
  '   Replace multiple CRs by ‹cr› or      ‹n cr›
  '   Replace multiple TBs by              ‹n tb›
  '   Replace multiple non-break spaces by ‹n nbs›
  '   Replace multiple CRLFs by            ‹n crlf›

  Dim InsStr As String
  Dim InxWsChar As Long
  Dim NumWsChar As Long
  Dim PosWsChar As Long
  Dim RetnVal As String
  Dim WsCharCrnt As Variant
  Dim WsCharValue As Variant
  Dim WsCharDspl As Variant

  WsCharValue = VBA.Array(" ", vbCr & vbLf, vbLf, vbCr, vbTab, Chr(160))
  WsCharDspl = VBA.Array("s", "crlf", "lf", "cr", "tb", "nbs")

  RetnVal = Text

  ' Replace each whitespace individually
  For InxWsChar = 0 To UBound(WsCharValue)
    RetnVal = Replace(RetnVal, WsCharValue(InxWsChar), "‹" & WsCharDspl(InxWsChar) & "›")
  Next

  ' Look for repeats. If found replace <x> by <n x>
  For InxWsChar = 0 To UBound(WsCharValue)
    'Debug.Assert InxWsChar <> 1
    PosWsChar = 1
    Do While True
      InsStr = "‹" & WsCharDspl(InxWsChar) & "›"
      PosWsChar = InStr(PosWsChar, RetnVal, InsStr & InsStr)
      If PosWsChar = 0 Then
        ' No [more] repeats of this <x>
        Exit Do
      End If
      ' Have <x><x>.  Count number of extra <x>s
      NumWsChar = 2
      Do While Mid(RetnVal, PosWsChar + NumWsChar * Len(InsStr), Len(InsStr)) = InsStr
        NumWsChar = NumWsChar + 1
      Loop
      RetnVal = Mid(RetnVal, 1, PosWsChar - 1) & _
                "‹" & NumWsChar & " " & WsCharDspl(InxWsChar) & "›" & _
                Mid(RetnVal, PosWsChar + NumWsChar * Len(InsStr))
      PosWsChar = PosWsChar + Len(InsStr) + Len(NumWsChar)

    Loop
  Next

  ' Restore any single spaces
  RetnVal = Replace(RetnVal, "‹" & WsCharDspl(0) & "›", " ")

  TidyTextForDspl = RetnVal

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! Fabulous answer! - Part 1 (mistake with "obj.HTMLBody" repeatedly used for replace actions): understood. I simply did not think it through well enough. - Part 2 (vbLf and vbCr): Good! I will try this. Replacing **all** CRLFs in the e-Mails will however probably mess up the important parts of them, so I will (later) have to find a way to affect only the string in question. - Your diagnostic tool: this looks great! - I will test everything later today, as soon as I have time (too many meetings today). - This comment so far is simply to tell you I read and appreciate your answer!

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann  The author of an Html document can include as many TBs, CRs and LFs as they wish to make the document more readable to a human.  Indenting nested tags is very common.  A long string of TBs, CRs and LFs will become one space at display time and will be ignored if next to a block tag.  I do not believe replacement of every CRLF in a document by a space will have an effect on the appearance.  However, I have thought of a Regex solution which you might prefer.  I will post it later today.

Comment: We have all made the mistake with Replace.  You may need a few "Duh!" moments before it becomes second nature.  In your question you mention problems finding tags but do not explain what you are trying to do.  If this is a separate issue, I suggest a new question.  There is no limit on the number of questions you can ask and small questions get answered more quickly than large questions.  In fact, large questions are often ignored or voted down and deleted.  Don't forget to avoid less-thans and ampersands in a question about tags.  Use character entities instead.

Comment: Dear Tony, here a quick interim report: With the one improvement in the Replace() function (to make it operate as a chain) the procedure in my production environment now already does what I want it to do! That's great! (The live procedure has a bit different search strings than in the example above, and it has an additional *Replace(NewBody, "<hr", "<p")* to make <hr> disappear whatever formatting is included.) - I will however continue working on this, particularly with your analytics tool, and report again here. - As my initial problem is solved anyway, I mark the question as solved. Cheers.

Comment: PS: Lesson on "less-thans" and ampersands: understood, thank you! Good advice! - Question of Chr(13) vs. vbCr: still to be examined. In practical terms, my e-mails are now clean on eye-sight. I will however analyze the HTML later today and see if CRLFs are removed or left in place by he procedure as I am using it currently.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann  Thank you for accepting my answer. I can post my Regex answer if you are interested. You liked by cut down diagnostic tool.  What you like to see the full version?

Comment: Hi Tony. I am indeed interested in both, the Regex answer, and the full diagnostic tool. (I have not yet tested your - cut down? - version published above due to a crazy work situation these days that keeps me away from such (fun) development tasks. I will post here as soon as I tested it.)

Answer (score 2):

**My full diagnostic routine**

The subroutine `InvestigateEmails()` will output to either the Immediate Window or a file on the desktop.  The Immediate Window is usually the more convenient but has a limit of about 200 lines.  So if the output is likely to be over 200 lines, output must be to a file.  If output is less than 200 lines, the choice is yours.

For output to the Immediate Window, review subroutine `OutSomeProperties`.  Add any properties that you wish to see but are missing.  Consider removing any properties not currently required.  Check that `#Const Selected = True`.

For output to a file, review subroutine `OutAllProperties`.  More correctly this should be “all properties of which I am aware and have ever been interested in.”  You may wish to check that all the properties of interest to you are included.  I recommend not removing any existing properties.  Check that `#Const Selected = False`.

Select the emails whose properties you wish to see.  Run subroutine `InvestigateEmails()`

This code uses **conditional compiling** which will be confusing to a programmer not familiar with this technique.  Either research conditional compiling or accept that it is doing something useful that you do not need to understand.

```
Option Explicit

' This code requires references to:
'    "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"
'   "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects n.n Library".  Tested with version 6.1.

Public Sub InvestigateEmails()

  ' Outputs all or selected properties of one or more emails.

  ' ========================================================================
  ' "Selected = True" to output a small number of properties for
  ' a small number of emails to the Immediate Window.
  ' "Selected = False" to output all properties for any number of emails
  ' to desktop file "InvestigateEmails.txt".
  #Const Selected = True
  ' ========================================================================

  ' Technique for locating desktop from answer by Kyle:
  '                     http://stackoverflow.com/a/17551579/973283

  Dim Exp As Explorer
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem

  #If Not Selected Then
    Dim FileBody As String
    Dim Fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim Path As String

    Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")
  #End If

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  If Exp.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("Please select one or more emails then try again", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  Else
    For Each ItemCrnt In Exp.Selection
      If ItemCrnt.Class = olMail Then
        #If Selected Then
          Call OutSomeProperties(ItemCrnt)
        #Else
          Call OutAllProperties(ItemCrnt, FileBody)
        #End If
      End If
    Next
  End If

  #If Not Selected Then
    Call PutTextFileUtf8NoBom(Path & "\InvestigateEmails.txt", FileBody)
  #End If

End Sub
Public Sub OutSomeProperties(ItemCrnt As Outlook.MailItem)

  ' Outputs selected properties of a MailItem to the Immediate Window.

  ' The Immediate Window can only display about 200 rows before the older
  ' rows start scrolling off the top.  This means this routine is only
  ' suitable for displaying a small number of simple properties.  Add or
  ' remove properties as necessary to meet the current requirement.

  Dim InxA As Long
  Dim InxR As Long

  Debug.Print "=============================================="
  With ItemCrnt
    Debug.Print "  EntryId: " & .EntryID
    Debug.Print "  Created: " & .CreationTime
    Debug.Print " Receiver: " & .ReceivedByName
    Debug.Print " Received: " & .ReceivedTime
    For InxR = 1 To .Recipients.Count
      Debug.Print "Recipient: " & .Recipients(InxR)
    Next
    Debug.Print "   Sender: " & .Sender
    Debug.Print " SenderEA: " & .SenderEmailAddress
    Debug.Print " SenderNm: " & .SenderName
    Debug.Print "   SentOn: " & .SentOn
    Debug.Print "  Subject: " & .Subject
    Debug.Print "       To: " & .To
    If .Attachments.Count > 0 Then
      Debug.Print "Attachments:"
      For InxA = 1 To .Attachments.Count
        Debug.Print "    " & InxA & ": " & .Attachments(InxA).DisplayName
      Next
    End If
  End With

End Sub
Sub OutAllProperties(ItemCrnt As Outlook.MailItem, ByRef FileBody As String)

  ' Adds all properties of a MailItem to FileBody.

  ' The phrase "all properties" should more correctly be "all properties
  ' that I know of and have ever been interested in".

  ' Source of PropertyAccessor information:
  '   https://www.slipstick.com/developer/read-mapi-properties-exposed-outlooks-object-model/

  Dim InxA As Long
  Dim InxR As Long
  Dim PropAccess As Outlook.propertyAccessor

  If FileBody <> "" Then
    FileBody = FileBody & String(80, "=") & vbLf
  End If

  With ItemCrnt
    FileBody = FileBody & "EntryId: " & .EntryID
    FileBody = FileBody & "From (Sender): " & .Sender
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "From (Sender name): " & .SenderName
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "From (Sender email address): " & _
                                                     .SenderEmailAddress
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "Subject: " & CStr(.Subject)
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "Received: " & Format(.ReceivedTime, "dmmmyy hh:mm:ss")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "To: " & .To
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "CC: " & .CC
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "BCC: " & .BCC
    If .Attachments.Count = 0 Then
      FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "No attachments"
    Else
      FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "Attachments:"
      FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "No.|Type|Path|Filename|DisplayName|"
      For InxR = 1 To .Recipients.Count
        FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "Recipient" & InxR & ": " & .Recipients(InxR)
      Next
      For InxA = 1 To .Attachments.Count
        With .Attachments(InxA)
          FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & InxA & "|"
          Select Case .Type
            Case olByValue
              FileBody = FileBody & "Val"
            Case olEmbeddeditem
              FileBody = FileBody & "Ebd"
            Case olByReference
              FileBody = FileBody & "Ref"
            Case olOLE
              FileBody = FileBody & "OLE"
            Case Else
              FileBody = FileBody & "Unk"
          End Select
          ' Not all types have all properties.  This code handles
          ' those missing properties of which I am aware.  However,
          ' I have never found an attachment of type Reference or OLE.
          ' Additional code may be required for them.
          Select Case .Type
            Case olEmbeddeditem
              FileBody = FileBody & "|"
            Case Else
              FileBody = FileBody & "|" & .Pathname
          End Select
          FileBody = FileBody & "|" & .FileName
          FileBody = FileBody & "|" & .DisplayName & "|"
        End With
      Next
    End If  ' .Attachments.Count = 0
    Call OutLongTextRtn(FileBody, "Text: ", .Body)
    Call OutLongTextRtn(FileBody, "Html: ", .HtmlBody)

    Set PropAccess = .propertyAccessor

    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_RECEIVED_BY_NAME: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0040001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0042001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_REPLY_RECIPIENT_NAMES: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0050001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_EMAIL_ADDRESS: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_RECEIVED_BY_EMAIL_ADDRESS: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0076001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS:" & vbLf & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_SENDER_NAME: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1A001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1F001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_DISPLAY_BCC: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E02001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_DISPLAY_CC: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E03001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf & "PR_DISPLAY_TO: " & _
                           PropAccess.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E04001E")
    FileBody = FileBody & vbLf

    Set PropAccess = Nothing

  End With

End Sub
Sub OutLongTextRtn(ByRef TextOut As String, ByVal Head As String, _
                          ByVal TextIn As String)

  ' * Break TextIn into lines of not more than 100 characters
  '   and append to TextOut.
  ' * The output is arranged so:
  '     xxxx|sssssssssssssss|
  '         |sssssssssssssss|
  '         |ssssssssss|
  '   where "xxxx" is the value of Head and "ssss..." are characters from
  '         TextIn.  The third line in the example could be shorter because:
  '           * it contains the last few characters of TextIn
  '           * there a linefeed in TextIn
  '           * a <xxx> string recording whitespace would have been split
  '             across two lines.

  If TextIn = "" Then
    ' Nothing to do
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Const LenLineMax As Long = 100

  Dim PosBrktEnd As Long     ' Last > before PosEnd
  Dim PosBrktStart As Long   ' Last < before PosEnd
  Dim PosNext As Long        ' Start of block to be output after current block
  Dim PosStart As Long       ' First character of TextIn not yet output

  TextIn = TidyTextForDspl(TextIn)
  TextIn = Replace(TextIn, "lf›", "lf›" & vbLf)

  PosStart = 1
  Do While True
    PosNext = InStr(PosStart, TextIn, vbLf)
    If PosNext = 0 Then
      ' No LF in [Remaining] TextIn
      'Debug.Assert False
      PosNext = Len(TextIn) + 1
    End If
    If PosNext - PosStart > LenLineMax Then
      PosNext = PosStart + LenLineMax
    End If
    ' Check for <xxx> being split across lines
    PosBrktStart = InStrRev(TextIn, "‹", PosNext - 1)
    PosBrktEnd = InStrRev(TextIn, "›", PosNext - 1)
    If PosBrktStart < PosStart And PosBrktEnd < PosStart Then
      ' No <xxx> within text to be displayed
      ' No change to PosNext
      'Debug.Assert False
    ElseIf PosBrktStart > 0 And PosBrktEnd > 0 And PosBrktEnd > PosBrktStart Then
      ' Last or only <xxx> totally within text to be displayed
      ' No change to PosNext
      'Debug.Assert False
    ElseIf PosBrktStart > 0 And _
           (PosBrktEnd = 0 Or (PosBrktEnd > 0 And PosBrktEnd < PosBrktStart)) Then
      ' Last or only <xxx> will be split across rows
      'Debug.Assert False
      PosNext = PosBrktStart
    Else
      ' Are there other combinations?
      Debug.Assert False
    End If

    'Debug.Assert Right$(Mid$(TextIn, PosStart, PosNext - PosStart), 1) <> "‹"

    If TextOut <> "" Then
      TextOut = TextOut & vbLf
    End If
    If PosStart = 1 Then
      TextOut = TextOut & Head & "|"
    Else
      TextOut = TextOut & Space(Len(Head)) & "|"
    End If
    TextOut = TextOut & Mid$(TextIn, PosStart, PosNext - PosStart) & "|"
    PosStart = PosNext
    If Mid$(TextIn, PosStart, 1) = vbLf Then
      PosStart = PosStart + 1
    End If
    If PosStart > Len(TextIn) Then
      Exit Do
    End If
  Loop

End Sub
Sub PutTextFileUtf8NoBom(ByVal PathFileName As String, ByVal FileBody As String)

  ' Outputs FileBody as a text file named PathFileName using
  ' UTF-8 encoding without leading BOM

  '  1Nov16  Copied from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4461250/973283
  '          but replaced literals with parameters.
  ' 15Aug17  Discovered routine was adding an LF to the end of the file.
  '          Added code to discard that LF.
  ' 11Oct17  Posted to StackOverflow
  '  9Aug18  Comment from rellampec suggested removal of adWriteLine from
  '          WriteTest statement would avoid adding LF.
  ' 30Sep18  Amended routine to remove adWriteLine from WriteTest statement
  '          and code to remove LF from file. Successfully tested new version.

  ' References: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4461250/973283
  '             https://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_ref_stream.asp

  Dim BinaryStream As Object
  Dim UTFStream As Object

  Set UTFStream = CreateObject("adodb.stream")

  UTFStream.Type = adTypeText
  UTFStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
  UTFStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
  UTFStream.Open
  UTFStream.WriteText FileBody

  UTFStream.Position = 3 'skip BOM

  Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("adodb.stream")
  BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary
  BinaryStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
  BinaryStream.Open

  UTFStream.CopyTo BinaryStream

  UTFStream.Flush
  UTFStream.Close
  Set UTFStream = Nothing

  BinaryStream.SaveToFile PathFileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
  BinaryStream.Flush
  BinaryStream.Close
  Set BinaryStream = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This afternoon I had finally a chance to test your cut-off version of the tool. It works flawlessly. Thus I also understood its bulit-in limitation of displaying only up to 200 lines of output in the immediate window.  I instantly thought: Well, then save the output into a file. Returning here, I now find your full routine made to do exactly this, and even more. Thank you very much! This is incredible support for my tiny project of developing a macro to mitigate the absurdities to which e-mail safety paranoia has led our municipal IT department. [cont.]

Comment: [Cont. from above] My macro already does the basic things I wanted it to do (kill certain repeating stuff in incoming e-mail), but with the help of your analytical tool I will be able to improve it considerably. Thank you, again!

Comment: Test of the tool: works flawlessly for me. HTML content of the e-mail is put into a .txt file in the "Desktop" folder. (On opening this file in an editor such as Notepad++ we see HMTL plus added line breaks for improving readability for the human eye, as specified in the tool). Great tool!