# Count number of attachments skip pictures in signature (based on objAttachments.Item(s).Size)

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to create a code that will parse Inbox folder in Outlook and organize emails based on several criteria.

1. If there is a number between brackets. For example (123456)
2. If there are attachments in email item. Attachment should be more than 10000 to skip Signatures

Logic:

- If both criteria match -> Send to Folder1
- If one of them does not match (attachments are missing or there is no number between brackets), send to Archive

Criteria 1 is functioning correct, but I have problems adding criteria 2 for attachments.

Here is my current code:

```
Private Sub olInboxMainItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    'On Error Resume Next

    Dim SubjectVar1 As String
    Dim openPos1 As Integer
    Dim closePos1 As Integer
    Dim midBit1 As String
    Dim objNamespace1 As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim destinationFolder1 As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim ArchiveFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim AttCount As Long

    Set objNamespace1 = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set destinationFolder1 = objNamespace1.Folders("mybox@mail.com").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Folder1")
    Set ArchiveFolder = objNamespace1.Folders("mybox@mail.com").Folders("Archive")

    Set objAttachments = Item.Attachments

    ' Check is there a number between brackets
    SubjectVar1 = Item.Subject
    openPos1 = InStr(SubjectVar1, "(")
    closePos1 = InStr(SubjectVar1, ")")
    midBit1 = Mid(SubjectVar1, openPos1 + 1, closePos1 - openPos1 - 1)

    ' Count number of attachments bigger than 10000 bytes
    For s = lngCount To 1 Step -1
      If objAttachments.Item(s).Size > 10000 Then

        ' Count attachments.
        AttCount = objAttachments.Item(s).Count

      End If
    Next s

    ' Perform actions
    If midBit1 = "" And AttCount < 1 Then
        Item.Move ArchiveFolder
        'GoTo EndOfScript
    Else
        'MsgBox (midBit)
        Item.Move destinationFolder1
        'GoTo EndOfScript
    End If

EndOfScript:

    Set destinationFolder1 = Nothing
    Set objNamespace1 = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here is a simple version I am trying to get working for selected email message:

```
Sub CountAttachmentsinSelectedEmails()

    Dim olSel As Selection
    Dim oMail As Object
    Dim s As Long
    Dim AttCount As Long
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim nRes
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim strFile As String

    Set olSel = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    For Each oMail In olSel

        For s = lngCount To 1 Step -1
        If objAttachments.Item(s).Size > 10000 Then

            strFile = objAttachments.Item(s).Count + 1

         End If
         Next s

    Next

    MsgBox ("There are " & strFile & " attachments in the ")

End Sub
```

Result is empty? No numbers at all

---

**EDIT 2:**

```
Sub CountAttachmentsinSelectEmails()

    Dim olSel As Selection
    Dim oMail As Object
    Dim s As Long
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim NumFiles As Long
    Dim oItem As Object

    Set olSel = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Set objAttachments = oItem.Attachments

    For Each oMail In olSel

        For s = objAttachments.Count To 1 Step -1
            If objAttachments.Item(s).Size > 10000 Then

                NumFiles = NumFiles + 1

             End If
         Next s

    Next

    Debug.Print NumFiles

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: /Whats wrong with your code?

Comment: This gives an error message saying "Argument is not optional", pointing to Item in `objAttachments.Item.Size`

Comment: Please in future always post the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Item.Attachments` is a collection therefore so is `objAttachments`.

A collection can have zero or more members.  `objAttachments.Count` is the number of members which you do not check.

You need to loop over the attachments to check their size and extension individually.   Signatures, logos and so on count as attachments but I assume you are not interested in them.  Could there be more than one interesting attachment?  Do you want a total size of 10,000 or any one attachment being more than 10,000 bytes?

When accessing the size you need to specify which attachment you are checking: `objAttachments.Item(Index).Size`.

The above should you give you some pointers but I can explain in more detail if necessary.

**Comments on edit 1**

You do not set `objAttachments` to anything.  Add `Set objAttachments = oItem.Attachments`.

In `For s = lngCount To 1 Step -1` you do not set `lngCount` to a value so it defaults to zero and the for body is never performed.  Try `For s = objAttachments.Count To 1 Step -1`.

`strFile` is a string but you are using it in a numeric expression.  This will work because the interpreter will evaluate the expression and then convert it to a string.  However, the value is `objAttachments.Item(s).Count + 1`.  If there are five attachments and any one of them is larger than 10,000 bytes, the answer will be six.

You need something like `Dim NumFiles As Long`.  This will be initialised to 0.  Within the `If` you need `NumFiles = NumFiles + 1`.

I rarely use MsgBox for diagnostics.  I find `Debug.Print NumFiles` more convenient.  If I want to stop execution, I use `Debug.Assert False`.

**Comments on Edit 2**

This is the routine I use to test new email handling macros.  The relevance is it show how to use Outlook’s Explorer correctly.

```
Sub TestNewMacro()

  ' Skeleton for testing a new mail item processing macro using Explorer
  ' Replace statement marked ##### with call of new macro.
  ' Add code to create parameters for new test macro and remove any code to
  ' create parameters for old test macro.

  Dim Exp As Explorer
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem
  Dim PathSave As String

  ' Technique for locating desktop from answer by Kyle:
  '                     http://stackoverflow.com/a/17551579/973283
  PathSave = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  If Exp.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("Please select one or more emails then try again", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  Else
    For Each ItemCrnt In Exp.Selection
      Call MacroToBeTested(ItemCrnt, PathSave)  ' #####
    Next
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this! My intention is to make code count number of attachments in email message that are bigger than 10000 bytes. Then I can make simple check if counted number > 1, perform action. If < 1, perform another action

Comment: You are welcome.  If you need some example code, just ask.

Comment: I have added my second attempt with simple code, but it does not work as well. If you can give me advice how to get code in EDIT section working, it would be very nice

Comment: There is still something wrong. O_o I have added EDIT2

Comment: You may find it useful to look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58000707/973283.  This answer includes the macro I use to diagnose problems with email handling macros.  The macro outputs selected properties to the Immediate Window or all properties I have ever been interested in to a file.  You may not need a diagnostic macro at the moment but you may be interested in how the macro accesses attachment properties.

Comment: @hatman  Sorry.  I found enough errors in the body of your macro that I did not check the envelope.  I have added a macro that I use for testing new email handling macros.  It shows how to use Explorer correctly which is what your macro is attempting.  You reference the collection of selected emails but you do not reference the individual emails within that collection.