# How to find all unaswered emails sent from client?

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to follow-up all emails sent from me to other users but where the other user never replied. It can be new emails or unreplied ones in ongoing conversations.

How can I get the last email sent from **me** in a conversation or new mail?

I'm running Microsoft Office 356 ProPlus Version 1908 (Build 11929.20606)

My VBA script finds emails in my inbox ('\firstname.lastname@domain.com\Inbox') and moves them to an "unanswered" sub-folder.

The problem is the emails are mostly from other users and when I filter on emails from me (by using default filter in the folder, e.g. from:"sender"), all I get is the  mails sent to myself or autogenerated mails from SharePoint server on my behalf (such as shared SharePoint sites with other users).

I tried to search my sent folder only ('\firstname.lastname@domain.com\Sent') and this lists the same items as when I filter on mails sent from me using the default folder-filter which were obtained when querying my inbox.

To decide which mails to put in my "unanswered" folder I tried the following:

1) "DASL search" by excluding all mails which are have the last executed verb set to "replied to all" or "replied to".

```
NOT ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003" = 102 OR "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003" = 103)
```

2) Using ConversationIndex, as i found online that unaswered mails have a ConversationIndex length = 44:

```
If Len(objVariant.ConversationIndex) = 44 Then
```

3) Using LastExecutedVerb. Noticed by checking the properties of an email in a conversation that emails sent by me as the latest item always had "PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED  0" when using:

```
Debug.Print "PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED", propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003")
```

SoIi tried filtering emails where the PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED = 0, but this lead to no emails being found at all.

Comment: Where are these emails?  I would expect the emails **from** you to be in folder Sent Items.  I would expect the emails **to** you to be in folder Inbox.  You are attempting to move some emails to an unanswered folder.  This suggests that to understand the state of a conversion, you need to look in three folders.  Have I correctly understand the issue?

Comment: Hi Tony! Thanks for your question, clarified my initial problem description based on it! The items are located in my inbox and my assumption is that the query automatically finds items in all folders including the Sent folder? I tried to query the sent-folder, but this only returned mails sent to myself or auto generated from sharepoint and not the last emails from me in a conversation.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED` check must be for the property missing (= null)

```
@SQL="http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003" is null
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry! I am using Outlook.Application.AdvancedSearch and it does not need/accept "@SQL"-prefix. But i changed my if-clause to use "is null" instead of "=0" and it manages to find items but the result is as before, still not showing the latest email sent from me in an ongoing conversation.

Comment: "The latest'? The query will return multiple items, it is your responsibility to pick the right one.

Comment: Sorry, yes the query returns multiple items. but when i search for emails from myself within the folder, I only get the ones sent to myself or those auto-generated from SharePoint on my behalf and not the latest mail sent by me in a conversation.

Comment: For the messages that are **not** returned by the query, did you check with OutlookSpy or MFCMAPI if PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED is set, and if it is, what the value of that property is?

Comment: Hi, used Debug.Print to read out the parameters of 3 mails in the same conversation. Conversation_Index_Length = 44 (sent from me), and 64 (reply to all) were not returned only index 54 for some reason:
`Conversation_Index_Length: 44
PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED 0 
PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME Null
PR_SUBJECT_PREFIX_PT_STRING8 
Conversation_Index_Length: 54
PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED 0 
PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME Null
PR_SUBJECT_PREFIX_PT_STRING8 RE: 
Conversation_Index_Length: 64
PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED 103 
PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME 2020-03-24 13:22:00 
PR_SUBJECT_PREFIX_PT_STRING8 RE:`

Comment: ran out of characters above, the mail with conversation_index_length = 64 is correctly excluded by the query since last_verb is = 103 (reply all). What I don't understand is why my first mail (index =  44) was also excluded by the query while the reply to it (index = 54) was included, although both didn't have last_verb set?

Comment: Does PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED = 0 mean the property is not set (null) Or that it is set to 0? Again, what do you see in OutlookSpy (click IMessage button)?

Comment: Hi, PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED  is not visible in the list of properties in OutlookSpy for the mails with conversation index 44, 54 . For mail with conversation index = 64 PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED is visible and set to 103. Seems PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED is null for the mails i'm looking for but why are they not returned by the query?

Comment: Are they returned by MAPIFolder.Items.Restrict?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, suddenly it all works now, perhaps a delay in outlook server caused the instant search in my "unanswered" folder not to show all items when filtering on mails from me? I realized that outlook nulls PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED when replying via mobile device or editing the recipient list, so even if people reply to my email the mails will still appear in my unanswered folder. This is ok since the "Show as Conversations" will catch those items. Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any suitable conversations and do not use SharePoint so cannot investigate your problem.  This is not an answer, instead I explain how I would investigate your requirement and develop a solution.

Outlook VBA has some powerful filters, but I have rarely been able to adapt them to my requirements.  When I have had a requirement like yours, there has not been one group of emails to be selected.  Instead I go through my emails discarding those with characteristic A or without characteristic B and then working with those that are left.  So, my code would be something like:

```
Dim Review As Boolean

For Inx = FldrSrc.Items.Count To 1 Step -1

  ItemCrnt = FldrSrc.Items(Inx)
  Review = True

  If ItemCrnt has CharacteristicA Then
    Review = False
  End If
  If Review Then
    If ItemCrnt does not have CharacteristicB Then
      Review = False
    End If
  End If
  If Review Then
    If ItemCrnt has CharacteristicC Then
      Review = False
    End If
  End If

  If Review Then
    ItemCrnt.Move FldrDest
  End If

Next
```

In the above code, I have accessed `FldrSrc.Items`.  You could access a filtered collection of items instead if you prefer.

You will notice that my `For-Loop` counts down.  This is important.  `FldrSrc.Items` is a collection in which each item is identified by its position.  Consider:

```
┌────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┐
│ Item 1 │ Item  2│ Item 3 │ Item 4 │ Item 5 │ Item 6 │ Item 7 │ Item 8 │ Item 9 │
└────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

Suppose I delete item 5.  Item 6 becomes item 5, item 7 becomes item 6 and so on:

```
┌────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┐
│ Item 1 │ Item  2│ Item 3 │ Item 4 │ Item 5 │ Item 6 │Item  7 │Item  8 │
│        │        │        │        │  was 6 │  was 7 │  was 8 │  was 9 │
└────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

If I am counting forwards, after removing item 5, I examine item 6.  But item 6 is the old item 7; I never examine the old item 6.

But if I am counting backwards, after removing item 5, I examine item 4 which has not moved.

I hope this explanation is clear.  If not, just accept that you always scan a collection backwards if you might remove items from it.

You then need to consider the body of the loop.  For each type of email, you need to identify some characteristic or characteristics that emails of that type must, or must not, have.  I believe my diagnostic routine will help with this task.  Visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/58000707/973283 and copy the code to a module.  Near the top you will find: `#Const Selected = True`.  This must be replaced by `#Const Selected = False`.  You also require references to the following libraries: "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects n.n Library".

Having done that, select one or more emails that you do **not** want copied to the unanswered folder.  Then run macro `InvestigateEmails()`.  The macro will create a file on your desktop named “InvestigateEmails.txt”.  This file will list the value of every property of the selected emails that I have every found useful.  Look through the unwanted emails and identify the properties that make them special.

These instructions may seem a little strange.  Run my macro and examine the output. I believe it will quickly become clear what you need to do.

Comment: Hi Tony, with help of InvestigateEmails() I learned that outlook nulls PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED when replying via mobile device or editing the recipient list making it a lot harder to see if an email was replied to in these cases. Conversation index length however increases so this could probably be used to further improve my script, but that is far too advanced for me. :)

Comment: @AmirHodzic  Do the replies contain a copy of the original email?  If so, that copy will probably start with something like "On Thu, 9 Jan 2020 at 12:40, &lt;a.j.dallimore&#40;xxxxxx.com&gt; wrote:".  Search for a heading line like this or perhaps a key phrase within the original body might find a reply.

Comment: Sorry the character entities in my last comment have not displayed correctly.  &lt;a.j.dallimore&#40;xxxxxx.com&gt; should read as <a.j.dallimore@xxxxxx.com>

Comment: I am pleased `InvestigateEmails` revealed some useful information.  Can I help any more?