# HTML table on outlook not showing completely

Tags: html, powershell, outlook

Hello I've a powershell that generates an HTML table and uses Send-MailMessage to send it trough outlook. Looks like only is supporting 25 lines. Can find if the issue is on my code or its a outlook configuration problem.

The HTML is fine, so it looks like the problem is on outlook

EMAIL
[image: OUTLOOK EMAIL]

HTML TABLE RUN ON THE BROWSER:

[image: HTML TABLE]

Power shell code:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, position=0)]
    [string] $DatabaseServer,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, position=1)]
    [string] $DatabaseName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, position=2)]
    [string] $TargetEmail
)
$query = "DECLARE @html nvarchar(MAX);
  EXEC spQueryToHtmlTable @html = @html OUTPUT,

  @query = 'SELECT 
  RUNID, LAUNCHEDBY, RUNSTART, PROCESSTYPE, PROCESSNAME 
  FROM mytable
  WHERE datediff(minute,RUNSTART,GETDATE()) > 15 AND RUNEND IS NULL', @orderBy = 'ORDER BY RUNSTART';
 SELECT @html as html
"
$ConString = "Server=$DatabaseServer;Database=$DatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout=30"
$result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ConnectionString $ConString
$body =  "The following processes have been locked for more than 15 minutes: `n" + $result.html

Send-MailMessage -To $TargetEmail -From “test@test.com”  -Subject “[$DatabaseName] Alert - Processes running for >= 15 mins“ -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer “smtp.smtp.com”
```

SQL Code:

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spQueryToHtmlTable]    Script Date: 15/04/2020 14:45:57 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spQueryToHtmlTable] 
(
  @query nvarchar(MAX), --A query to turn into HTML format. It should not include an ORDER BY clause.
  @orderBy nvarchar(MAX) = NULL, --An optional ORDER BY clause. It should contain the words 'ORDER BY'.
  @html nvarchar(MAX) = NULL OUTPUT --The HTML output of the procedure.
)
AS
BEGIN   
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF @orderBy IS NULL BEGIN
    SET @orderBy = ''  
  END

  SET @orderBy = REPLACE(@orderBy, '''', '''''');

  DECLARE @realQuery nvarchar(MAX) = '
    DECLARE @headerRow nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @cols nvarchar(MAX);    

    SELECT * INTO #dynSql FROM (' + @query + ') sub;

    SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + '', '''''''', '', '''') + ''['' + name + ''] AS ''''td''''''
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = object_id(''tempdb..#dynSql'')
    ORDER BY column_id;

    SET @cols = ''SET @html = CAST(( SELECT '' + @cols + '' FROM #dynSql ' + @orderBy + ' FOR XML PATH(''''tr''''), ELEMENTS XSINIL) AS nvarchar(max))''    

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @cols, N''@html nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT'', @html=@html OUTPUT

    SELECT @headerRow = COALESCE(@headerRow + '''', '''') + ''<th>'' + name + ''</th>'' 
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = object_id(''tempdb..#dynSql'')
    ORDER BY column_id;

    SET @headerRow = ''<tr>'' + @headerRow + ''</tr>'';

    SET @html = ''<table border="1">'' + @headerRow + @html + ''</table>'';    
    ';

  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @realQuery, N'@html nvarchar(MAX) OUTPUT', @html=@html OUTPUT
END
```

Can you help me finding that problem? Thank!

Comment: Looking at the code might help but first I would look at the Html body of the email.  Why does output suddenly stop mid cell?  Is the remainder of the table missing?  Has some corrupt Html been inserted in row 25?  Has the Html body or the email reached some size limit?  To answer these questions, try the macro in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58000707/973283.  This is a diagnostic macro that allows you to see properties of an email.  In particular, it will output the entire Html body to a file in a human-readable format.  ...

Comment: How does the content of `$result.html` look like?

Comment: ...  The macro needs references to 
"Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects n.n Library".   Ask if you do not know what that means.  Near the top of the macro, you will find `#Const Selected = True`.  Replace that with `#Const Selected = False`.  Select the email that mis-displays and then run macro `InvestigateEmails()`.  Study at file “InvestigateEmails.txt” which will be on your desktop.  Can you see anything that might be worth describing in your question?

Comment: BTW.  The last line of your Power Shell code contains smart double quotes.  Can Power Shell handle these?  I would replace them with ordinary double quotes.

Comment: Thank you for the help Tony. I'll check the macro.

Comment: Related to the HTML , the second screen yous the HTML that I'm sending.. looks fine if you run it on a browser

Comment: Just edited it to make it more clear