# Extract Outlook e-mail content between two known constants to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, search, outlook, extract

We are creating a website. There is an option to create a form. Users can submit the form and the content of the form is sent to us as an e-mail.

We however need the information gathered in an Excel sheet.

I couldn't make any of the already posted answers work for me.

[image: E-mail]

I have no control over the format of the e-mail above. Also one of the content comes from a multiple line textbox.

Would it be possible to search for two constants and get the content from between the two?
For example, get everything between "3. Description:" and "4. Category:" and then place that in to the desired Excel cell.

Answer (score 1):

Set up the body of the email to be in a string array variable and use split to get the data you need.

```
dim str() as string
str = split(outlookmail.body,"")
```

Then loop through the array to output to the cell.

```
flag = true

For i=Lbound(str) to uBound(str)
   
   if (inStr(1,str(i),"3. Description:") then 
      do while <> inStr(1,str(i),"4. Category:"
        i=i+1

        if flag then
           cells(i,1).value = str(i)
           flag = false
        else
           cells(i,1).value = cells(i,1).value & vbnewline & str(i)
        end if
      loop
   end if 
next i
```

Answer (score -1):

You are asking too much for a single question, but I will try to get you started by indicating the topics you will have to research.

Outlook will accept Text, Html or Rich Text Format (RTF) email bodies.  I have never seen a RTF email so I doubt your website is sending RTF emails.  The emails will have a Text body or an Html body or both.  If the emails have both, the user will only see the Html body on the screen although both versions are accessible to a VBA macro.  You show “1. Name”, “2. E-mail”, “3. Description” and “4. Category” underlined.  Underlining is only available with Html bodies so, if your image is correct, you have Html bodies.  I suspect, you only have Text bodies.  However, if your website is sending Html bodies, Outlook will create a text version by stripping out all the Html tags and replacing them with Carriage Return LineFeeds (CRLFs).

The text body will be:

```
1. Name¶
John Doe¶
¶
2. E-mail¶
example@address.com¶
¶
3.Description¶
In this description¶
users can write in multiple lines. ¶
As far as I know there is also no character limit. ¶
¶
4. Category¶
Option 2¶
¶
```

where the `¶`s will be a single LF, CR LF or CR LF CR LF depending on how the text body was created.

If you visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/58000707/973283 you will find the diagnostic routine I use to discover the exact format of emails.  You will need to copy that macro to Outlook and following the instructions.

Once you know the separator, I guess the easiest approach is to use:

```
Dim Lines() as String

Lines = Split(Email.Body, vbCRLF)
```

where you will need to replace vbCRLF by the appropriate separator.

`Lines` is an array with one entry per line.  It will be easy to step down the array and find the headers.  LinetonKoch shows you how to do that.  Your suggestion of searching the body for the headers is possible using `InStr`.  The trouble is that I expect the separators to be CRLF and Excel treats CR as an unknown character, which displays as a square, so you will have to remove them.

The above should give you an idea of how to process these emails.

My diagnostic routine requires the user to identify the email to be processed.  I assume you would rather the identification is automatic.  Your choice is an Outlook Rule with an attached macro or a New Item Event Routine.  I suspect the New Item Event Routine approach will be easier.

You will have to decide if the New Item Event Routine will open a workbook for each new email or output the email to a text file and import to a workbook at intervals.  The best approach will depend on the number of emails and how soon after arrival you want the emails processed.