# VBA - Convert string to UNICODE

Tags: excel, vba, unicode, cyrillic

I need to convert the string HTML from a mix of Cyrillic and Latin symbols to UNICODE.

I tried the following:

```
Public HTML As String
    Sub HTMLsearch()

    GetHTML ("http://nfs.mobile.bg/pcgi/mobile.cgi?act=3&slink=6jkjov&f1=1")
    MsgBox HTML
    HTML = StrConv(HTML, vbUnicode)
    MsgBox HTML
End Sub

Function GetHTML(URL As String) As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .Send
        HTML = .ResponseText
    End With
End Function
```

You can see what is before and after the StrConv. If you like to get the html in a file, you can use the following code:

```
Public HTML As String
    Sub HTMLsearch()

    GetHTML ("http://nfs.mobile.bg/pcgi/mobile.cgi?act=3&slink=6jkjov&f1=1")

    Dim path As String

    path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\html.txt"
    Open path For Output As #1
    Print #1, HTML
    Close #1

    HTML = StrConv(HTML, vbUnicode)

    path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\htmlUNICODE.txt"
    Open path For Output As #1
    Print #1, HTML
    Close #1
End Sub

Function GetHTML(URL As String) As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .Send
        HTML = .ResponseText
    End With
End Function
```

IDEAS?

Comment: It would help to explain what the code does (or doesn't do) in relation to what you expect/want it to do.  i.e. *what is the actual problem here*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

VBA's support for Unicode is not all that great.

It is possible to handle Unicode strings, but you will not be able to see the actual characters with `Debug.Print` or `MsgBox` - they will appear as `?` there.

You can set *Control Panel > Region and Language > Administrative tab > "Current language for non-Unicode programs"* to "Russian" switch to a different code page, which would allow you to see Cyrillic letters in VBA message boxes instead of question marks. But that's only a cosmetic change.

---

Your real problem is something else here.

The server (nfs.mobile.bg) sends the document as `Content-Type: text/html`. There is no information about character encoding. That means the receiver must figure out character encoding on its own.

A browser does that by looking at the response byte stream and making guesses. In your case, a helpful `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">` tag is present in the HTML source. Therefore, the byte stream should be interpreted as `Windows-1251`, which happens to be the Cyrillic ANSI code page in Windows.

So, we do not even have Unicode here!

In the absence of any additional info, the `responseText` property of the `XMLHTTP` object defaults to `us-ascii`. The extended characters from the Cyrillic alphabet are not present in ASCII, so they will be converted to *actual* question marks and are lost. That's why you can't use `responseText` for anything.

However, the *original* bytes of the response are still available, in the `responseBody` property, which is an array of `Byte`.

In VBA you must do the same thing a browser would do. You must interpret the byte-stream as a certain character set. The `ADODB.Stream` object can do that for you, and it's pretty straight-forward, too:

```
' reference: "Microsoft XML, v6.0" (or any other version)
' reference: "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 library" (or any other version)
Option Explicit

Sub HTMLsearch()
    Dim url As String, html As String
    
    url = "http://nfs.mobile.bg/pcgi/mobile.cgi?act=3&slink=6jkjov&f1=1"
    html = GetHTML(url, "Windows-1251")
    
    ' Cyrillic characters are supported in Office, so they will appear correctly
    ActiveDocument.Range.InsertAfter html
End Sub

Function GetHTML(Url As String, Optional Charset As String = "UTF-8") As String
    Dim request As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim converter As New ADODB.stream
    
    ' fetch page
    request.Open "GET", Url, False
    request.send
    
    ' write raw bytes to the stream
    converter.Open
    converter.Type = adTypeBinary
    converter.Write request.responseBody
    
    ' switch the stream to text mode and set charset
    converter.Position = 0
    converter.Type = adTypeText
    converter.Charset = Charset
    
    ' read text characters from the stream, close the stream
    GetHTML = converter.ReadText
    converter.Close
End Function
```

I've been using MS Word here and calling `HTMLsearch()` properly writes Cyrillic characters to the page. They still do appear as `?` in a `MsgBox` for me, though, but now that's purely a display problem, caused by the fact that VBA-created UI cannot deal with Unicode.

Comment: @ Tomalak : I don't believe I've seen a better answer and explanation. Thank you very much for the support!

Comment: @Vihar The final bit of info: Internally, all VBA strings are Unicode (UTF-16, just like all strings in Windows). So the result of `converter.ReadText` actually *already is* a Unicode string. What `converter.Charset = "Windows-1251"` effectively does is informing the stream  *which ANSI code page it needs to use* to convert the contained bytes to Unicode.

Comment: e.g. byte `0xC1` in the input → interpreted as character `Б` using code page 1251 → mapped to `U+0431` (CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER BE) in Unicode (UTF-16 representation in memory: 2 bytes `0x0431`)

Comment: Thats a great answer from Tomalak, and it seemed awesome, I got it to run, but it did not work in the end on my production data that contains 100s of languages. see my answer below that did work.

Comment: This solution can only work in Windows. Excel for Mac can't do it. It doesn't understand MSXML2.XMLHTTP, for one.

Comment: @Br.Bill That's true, the whole solution is geared towards Windows. On Mac Office, alternative approaches of fetching data via HTTP must be used. Conditional compilation (`#If Mac Then` ... `#Else` ... `#End If`) could be used to integrate them into the same codebase.

Comment: @Br.Bill Here's a issue/workaround thread in a repository which looks quite useful in general: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web/issues/65

Comment: Speak about an educating answer. This was the direct method to read a Russian site - though the _charset_ was UTF-8, but that did you also explain.

Answer (score 5):

My production order data comes from many countries. this is the only vba function I could find that really works.

```
Private Const CP_UTF8 = 65001

Private Declare Function MultiByteToWideChar Lib "kernel32" ( _
   ByVal CodePage As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
   ByVal lpMultiByteStr As Long, ByVal cchMultiByte As Long, _
   ByVal lpWideCharStr As Long, ByVal cchWideChar As Long) As Long


Public Function sUTF8ToUni(bySrc() As Byte) As String
   ' Converts a UTF-8 byte array to a Unicode string
   Dim lBytes As Long, lNC As Long, lRet As Long

   lBytes = UBound(bySrc) - LBound(bySrc) + 1
   lNC = lBytes
   sUTF8ToUni = String$(lNC, Chr(0))
   lRet = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, VarPtr(bySrc(LBound(bySrc))), lBytes, StrPtr(sUTF8ToUni), lNC)
   sUTF8ToUni = Left$(sUTF8ToUni, lRet)
End Function
```

Example Usage:

```
Dim sHTML As String
Dim bHTML() As Byte
bHTML = GetHTML("http://yoururlhere/myorderdata.php")
sHTML = sUTF8ToUni(bHTML)
sHTML = Mid(sHTML, 2)  'strip off Byte Order Mark: EF BB BF
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "doesn't work" and give an example where my function fails?

Comment: This solution can only work in Windows. Excel for Mac can't do it. It doesn't have the kernel32 library.