# Arrange Cells in range based on size of string

Tags: vba, excel

I am wondering if it is possible for excel to sort a range of cells based on the sum of the unicode values of the text in the string.

For example, I have a range as shown below

```
abc  
bde  
fgh  
bbc
```

and the result of the formula would produce in a seperate range

```
abc
bbc
bde
fgh
```

I am not sure if this type of thing would require a vba solution or if there is a way to use array functions to get this result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And the normal Sort function on the ribbon does not work?  Please show an example that would not sort properly with the sort function on the ribbon. The above will.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. I want to be able to change the input range and have the results update automatically in the second range.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest solving this problem as a two pronged approach:

1. Create a function to convert UTF8 to Unicode (see [VBA - Convert string to UNICODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810324/vba-convert-string-to-unicode))
2. Create a column to store the results of the function for each row's string value
3. Sort your data using the built-in sort based on the Unicode value column