# How to make Japanese text readable on userform in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a report that extracts data from MS Access and it's Japanese text but all I can see when I load the data in my userform is ???????. Can anyone pls advice on this?

Comment: this would be a good starting point:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810324/vba-convert-string-to-unicode

Comment: @tom preston thank you bigtime! :) I hope this link could help me.