# vba api website scraping for given date period currency rates

Tags: vba, api, get

I need help, for taking currency rates from website, via api. I need currency rates from one website, but it gives only in a table only for exact date. I need to change query every time, and then select the row where in the table my preferrred currency rate is shown.

```
Sub get()
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;https://cbr.ru/currency_base/daily/?UniDbQuery.Posted=True&UniDbQuery.To=01.07.2021" 
     _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .CommandType = 0
    .Name = "?UniDbQuery.Posted=True&UniDbQuery.To=01.07"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Range("A36").Select
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;https://cbr.ru/currency_base/daily/?UniDbQuery.Posted=True&UniDbQuery.To=02.07.2021" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .CommandType = 0
    .Name = "?UniDbQuery.Posted=True&UniDbQuery.To=02.07"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Range("F40").Select
End Sub
```

I need to take it from a period of time and only the currency let's say on 45th row.
Can anyone help with, "GET" request api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My function `ExchangeRatesCbr` returns a four dimensional array of the currencies listed and their current exchange rate:

```vb
' Retrieve the current exchange rates from the Central Bank of the Russian
' Federation having RUB as the base currency.
' The rates are returned as an array and cached until the next update.
' The rates are updated once a day at about UTC 13:00.
'
' Source:
'   https://cbr.ru/eng/currency_base/daily/
'
' Note:
'   The Central Bank of the Russian Federation has set the exchange rates of
'   foreign currencies against the ruble without assuming any liability to
'   buy or sell foreign currency at the rates.
'
' Example:
'   Dim Rates As Variant
'   Rates = ExchangeRatesCbr()
'   Rates(9, 0) -> 2018-10-06       ' Publishing date.
'   Rates(9, 1) -> "DKK"            ' Currency code.
'   Rates(9, 2) -> 10.2697          ' Exchange rate.
'   Rates(9, 3) -> "Danish Krone"   ' Currency name in English.
'
' 2018-10-07. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function ExchangeRatesCbr( _
    Optional ByVal LanguageCode As String) _
    As Variant

    ' Operational constants.
    '
    ' API endpoints.
    Const RuServiceUrl  As String = "https://cbr.ru/currency_base/daily/"
    Const EnServiceUrl  As String = "https://cbr.ru/eng/currency_base/daily/"
    
    ' Functional constants.
    '
    ' Page encoding.
    Const Characterset  As String = "UTF-8"
    ' Async setting.
    Const Async         As Variant = False
    ' Class name of data table.
    Const DataClassName As String = "data"
    ' Field items of html table.
    Const CodeField     As Integer = 1
    Const NameField     As Integer = 3
    Const UnitField     As Integer = 2
    Const RateField     As Integer = 4
    ' Locater/header for publishing date: "DT":".
    Const DateHeader    As String = """DT"":"""
    ' Length of formatted date: 2000-01-01.
    Const DateLength    As Integer = 10
    
    ' Update hour (UTC).
    Const UpdateHour    As Date = #1:00:00 PM#
    ' Update interval: 24 hours.
    Const UpdatePause   As Integer = 24
    ' English language code.
    Const EnglishCode   As String = "en"
    ' Russion language code.
    Const RussianCode   As String = "ru"
    

#If EarlyBinding Then
    ' Microsoft XML, v6.0.
    Dim XmlHttp         As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    ' Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library.
    Dim Stream          As ADODB.Stream
    ' Microsoft HTML Object Library.
    Dim Document        As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim Scripts         As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim Script          As MSHTML.HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim Tables          As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim Table           As MSHTML.HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim Rows            As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim Row             As MSHTML.HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim Fields          As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

    Set XmlHttp = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    Set Stream = New ADODB.Stream
    Set Document = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
#Else
    Dim XmlHttp         As Object
    Dim Stream          As Object
    Dim Document        As Object
    Dim Scripts         As Object
    Dim Script          As Object
    Dim Tables          As Object
    Dim Table           As Object
    Dim Rows            As Object
    Dim Row             As Object
    Dim Fields          As Object
    
    Set XmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    Set Stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    Set Document = CreateObject("htmlfile")
#End If

    Static Rates()      As Variant
    Static LastCall     As Date
    Static LastCode     As String
    
    Dim ServiceUrl      As String
    Dim RateCount       As Integer
    Dim Published       As String
    Dim ValueDate       As Date
    Dim ThisCall        As Date
    Dim Text            As String
    Dim Index           As Integer
    Dim Unit            As Double
    Dim ScaledRate      As Double
    Dim TrueRate        As Double
    
    If StrComp(LanguageCode, RussianCode, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        LanguageCode = RussianCode
        ServiceUrl = RuServiceUrl
    Else
        LanguageCode = EnglishCode
        ServiceUrl = EnServiceUrl
    End If
    
    If LastCode = LanguageCode And DateDiff("h", LastCall, UtcNow) < UpdatePause Then
        ' Return cached rates.
    Else
        ' Retrieve updated rates.
    
        ' Define default result array.
        ' Redim for four dimensions: date, code, rate, name.
        ReDim Rates(0, 0 To 3)
        Rates(0, RateDetail.Date) = NoValueDate
        Rates(0, RateDetail.Code) = NeutralCode
        Rates(0, RateDetail.Rate) = NeutralRate
        Rates(0, RateDetail.Name) = NeutralName
        
        ' Retrieve data.
        XmlHttp.Open "GET", ServiceUrl, Async
        XmlHttp.Send
        If XmlHttp.Status = HttpStatus.OK Then
            ' Retrieve and convert the page.
            ' The default character set cannot be used. See:
            ' https://stackoverflow.com/a/23812869/3527297
            
            ' Write the raw bytes to the stream.
            Stream.Open
            Stream.Type = adTypeBinary
            Stream.Write XmlHttp.responseBody
            ' Read text characters from the stream applying the character set.
            Stream.Position = 0
            Stream.Type = adTypeText
            Stream.Charset = Characterset
            ' Copy the page to the document object.
            Document.body.innerHTML = Stream.ReadText
        
            ' Search the scripts to locate the publishing date.
            Set Scripts = Document.getElementsByTagName("script")
            ValueDate = Date
            For Each Script In Scripts
                Text = Script.innerHTML
                If InStr(Text, "uniDbQuery_Data =") > 0 Then
                    Published = Left(Split(Text, DateHeader)(1), DateLength)
                    If IsDate(Published) Then
                        ValueDate = CDate(Published)
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        
            ' Search the tables to locate the data table.
            ' Doesn't work with late binding.
            ' Set Tables = Document.getElementsByClassName("data")
            Set Tables = Document.getElementsByTagName("table")
            For Each Table In Tables
                If Table.className = DataClassName Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            
            If Not Table Is Nothing Then
                ' The table was found.
                Set Rows = Table.getElementsByTagName("tr")
                ' Reduce the count by one to skip the header row.
                RateCount = Rows.Length - 1
                ' Redim for four dimensions: date, code, rate, name.
                ReDim Rates(0 To RateCount - 1, 0 To 3)
                
                ' Fill the array of rates.
                For Index = LBound(Rates, 1) To UBound(Rates, 1)
                    ' Offset Index by one to skip the header row.
                    Set Row = Rows.Item(Index + 1)
                    ' Get the fields of this rate.
                    Set Fields = Row.getElementsByTagName("td")
                    
                    ' The returned rates are scaled to hold four decimals only.
                    ' Calculate the true (non-scaled) rate.
                    ScaledRate = Val(Replace(Fields.Item(RateField).innerText, ",", "."))
                    Unit = Val(Fields.Item(UnitField).innerText)
                    TrueRate = ScaledRate / Unit
                    
                    Rates(Index, RateDetail.Date) = ValueDate
                    Rates(Index, RateDetail.Code) = Fields.Item(CodeField).innerText
                    Rates(Index, RateDetail.Rate) = TrueRate
                    Rates(Index, RateDetail.Name) = Fields.Item(NameField).innerHTML
                Next
            End If
            
            ThisCall = ValueDate + UpdateHour
            ' Record requested language and publishing time of retrieved rates.
            LastCode = LanguageCode
            LastCall = ThisCall
            
        End If
    End If
    
    ExchangeRatesCbr = Rates

End Function
```

From this you can select the currency you are interested in, or you can use the helper function, `CurrencyConvertCbr`, to pick the currency and conversion factor directly:

```vb
' Returns the current conversion factor from Rubel to another currency based on
' the official exchange rates published by the Central Bank of the Russian
' Federation.
'
' Optionally, the conversion factor can be calculated from any other of the
' published exchange rates. Exchange rates from or to other currencies than
' RUB are calculated from RUB by triangular calculation.
'
' If an invalid or unpublished currency code is passed, a conversion factor
' of zero is returned.
'
' Examples, typical:
'   CurrencyConvertCbr("DKK")           ->  0.0973738278625471
'   CurrencyConvertCbr("DKK", "EUR")    ->  7.46477501777072
'   CurrencyConvertCbr("AUD")           ->  0.021253081696846
'   CurrencyConvertCbr("AUD", "DKK")    ->  0.2182627731021
'   CurrencyConvertCbr("DKK", "AUD")    ->  4.58163334858857
'   CurrencyConvertCbr("EUR", "DKK")    ->  0.133962510272498
'   CurrencyConvertCbr("", "DKK")       -> 10.2697
'   CurrencyConvertCbr("EUR")           ->  0.013044442415309
' Examples, neutral code.
'   CurrencyConvertCbr("AUD", "XXX")    ->  1
'   CurrencyConvertCbr("XXX", "AUD")    ->  1
'   CurrencyConvertCbr("XXX")           ->  1
' Examples, invalid code.
'   CurrencyConvertCbr("XYZ")           ->  0
'   CurrencyConvertCbr("DKK", "XYZ")    ->  0
'
' 2018-10-07. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function CurrencyConvertCbr( _
    ByVal IsoTo As String, _
    Optional ByVal IsoFrom As String = RubelCode) _
    As Double
    
    Dim Rates()     As Variant
    
    Dim RateTo      As Double
    Dim RateFrom    As Double
    Dim Factor      As Double
    Dim Index       As Integer
    
    If IsoFrom = "" Then
        IsoFrom = RubelCode
    End If
    If IsoTo = "" Then
        IsoTo = RubelCode
    End If
    
    If IsoTo = NeutralCode Or IsoFrom = NeutralCode Then
        Factor = NeutralRate
    ElseIf IsoTo = IsoFrom Then
        Factor = NeutralRate
    Else
        Rates() = ExchangeRatesCbr
    
        If IsoTo = RubelCode Then
            RateTo = NeutralRate
        Else
            For Index = LBound(Rates) To UBound(Rates)
                If Rates(Index, RateDetail.Code) = IsoTo Then
                    RateTo = Rates(Index, RateDetail.Rate)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
        
        If RateTo > NoRate Then
            If IsoFrom = RubelCode Then
                RateFrom = NeutralRate
            Else
                For Index = LBound(Rates) To UBound(Rates)
                    If Rates(Index, RateDetail.Code) = IsoFrom Then
                        RateFrom = Rates(Index, RateDetail.Rate)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            Factor = RateFrom / RateTo
        End If
        
    End If
    
    CurrencyConvertCbr = Factor

End Function
```

To retrieve the rates for a historic date, apply the last parameter, for example for 2020-11-02, as shown here:

```html
https://cbr.ru/eng/currency_base/daily/?UniDbQuery.Posted=True&UniDbQuery.To=02%2F11%2F2020
```

That my function won't do, but it should be easy for you to adjust.

Full source at GitHub: [VBA.CurrencyExchange](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.CurrencyExchange)

Disclosure: The linked page contains extensive code written by me only.

Comment: It 's difficult to get into your code, but anyway thanks Gustav. I need the information to be taken from this page. to be put as a table into excel;  https://cbr.ru/currency_base/dynamics/?UniDbQuery.Posted=True&UniDbQuery.so=1&UniDbQuery.mode=1&UniDbQuery.date_req1=&UniDbQuery.date_req2=&UniDbQuery.VAL_NM_RQ=R01020&UniDbQuery.From=01.07.2021&UniDbQuery.To=01.10.2021

Comment: Yes, that what my code (and the attached demo) does, though for the English page and for the current date only. For a historic date's data, that date must be appended the URL formatted as shown above.