# Print to text file - encrypted text shows as question marks

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following encrypted text in cell A1:

```
ԓԗՃխՓ՛Րե՘Ր՞՚ըՖՑ՟խՑՙՔը՟՗՝ՇխՑ
```

I am trying to write this in a text file but the text shows as question marks characters `?????????????????` in the text file.

Here is my code:

```
textFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\customfile.txt"
FF = VBA.FreeFile
Open textFilePath For Output As #FF
Print #FF, CStr(Sheet1.Cells(1,1).Value)
Close #FF
```

FYI: If I manually copy and paste the value of cell A1 in notepad, the text shows fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write like a normal text... You need to write like UTF-8:

```
Dim fsT As Object
Set fsT = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
fsT.Type = 2 'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
fsT.Charset = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data.
fsT.Open 'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
fsT.WriteText Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value
fsT.SaveToFile "e:\0\customfile.txt", 2 'Save binary data To disk
```

taken from:

[Save text file UTF-8 encoded with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524703/save-text-file-utf-8-encoded-with-vba)