# Stream write XML file with VBA in correct encoding

Tags: excel, xml, vba, encoding, stream

I have an API response in an xml format which I request via vba and want to store in an xml file.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim OUTPUT_file As Object
Dim objXMLHTTP As Object

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

xml_file_path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\XML-Files\" & job_id & ".xml"
Set OUTPUT_file = objFSO.CreateTextFile(xml_file_path, True, True)

'API Request with objXMLHTTP Object

If objXMLHTTP.readyState = 4 Then
    OUTPUT_file.Write objXMLHTTP.responseText
    OUTPUT_file.Close
End If
```

At a later point I want to load the xml files back into the application. I do this with the following code:

```
Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
objXML.Load (xml_file_path)

MsgBox objXML.parseError.reason
'returns: "Switch from current encoding to specified encoding not supported."
```

Unfortunately the xml file's content is not recognized. (The objXML object stays empty).

The file itself looks good. When viewing it with a text editor, I can see the content.

Loading the xml files from other sources works fine. I therefore expect the problem to be somewhere where I create and write the file.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check whether you're getting an error by adding `MsgBox objXML.parseError.reason` after you've loaded your xml document.  Does it give an error?  If so, which one?

Comment: I get this error reason: 'Switch from current encoding to specified encoding not supported.'

Comment: When FileSystemObject is used to create a text file as Unicode, as you're doing in your code, it probably uses UTF-16 encoding. Whereas your XML file is probably marked as using a different encoding, such as UTF-8, hence the error.

Comment: You can open your XML file, and check at the very top for the specified encoding.  For example, if it in fact is UTF-8, you'll see `encoding="UTF-8"`.  Which encoding does it specify?

Comment: Files created in vba as well as files from other sources that don't lead to errors have the following header: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> However, I think this string is just part of the textresponse from the API.

Answer (score 0):

The helpful comments of [Domenic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6585761/domenic) as well as the post ([save-text-file-utf-8-encoded-with-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524703/save-text-file-utf-8-encoded-with-vba)) let me to a working solution.

Storing text in a FileSystemObject file results in an Unicode UTF-16 encoding. This seems to be independent of the encoding tag written into the xml file as part of the API response.

> ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

The MSXML2.DOMDocument60 expects the encoding to be UTF-8 (as stated in the encoding tag). An error occurs:

> "Switch from current encoding to specified encoding not supported."

Storing the API response in a txt file with UTF-8 encoding solves the problem.

Here is the updated code:

```
Dim objXMLHTTP As Object
Dim OUTPUT_file As Object
Set OUTPUT_file = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
OUTPUT_file.Type = 2
OUTPUT_file.Charset = "utf-8"

xml_file_path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\XML-Files\" & job_id & ".xml"

'API Request with objXMLHTTP Object

If objXMLHTTP.readyState = 4 Then
    OUTPUT_file.Open
    OUTPUT_file.WriteText objXMLHTTP.responseText
    OUTPUT_file.SaveToFile xml_file_path, 2
End If
```