# VBA - Handling folder name with utf8 characters

Tags: vba

I'm using `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)` to pick a folder and it handles well folders with utf8 names.
**But** when I try to `Debug.Print` the result of `SelectedItems(1)` or save it to a config file or do anything, I loose the accents of the folder.

For example:
Original folder:
`"D:\Śākta"`

'Debug.Print' or saving into an utf8 file result saves:
`"D:\Sakta"` *(removed all the accents)*

The problem is that I try to save the selected folder to a config file and when I try to load it, next time it will of course won't recognize as a real folder because of the missing accents.

**How to get the real name of the folder with the accents to be able to save it after, not this "representation" of it?**

Update:
Just checked, and even the InputBox kills the accents!

Comment: `Debug.Print` is limited by the VBA editor's lack of support for Unicode. I wouldn't worry about that -- but being able to save them to a file is of course more important. Please provide a [mcve] which shows how you are trying to save it.

Comment: Yes, VB strings are Unicode internally, only the IDE (such as the console) and UI elements (such as MsgBox) are not. When you save the selected path to a Unicode (!) file, does it stay intact?

Comment: This question might help (it is close to being a duplicate question): [Save text file utf-8 encoded with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2524703/4996248).

Answer (score 1):

@John Coleman's answer solved the issue switching the file saving to 'ADODB.Stream'

Here is an example of reading and writing config file supporting UTF8:

```vb
Public Function fileExists(ByVal fullFilename As String) As Boolean
    fileExists = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").fileExists(fullFilename)
End Function


Public Function ReadTextFile(ByVal sPath As String) As String
    If fileExists(sPath) Then
        Dim fsT As Object
        Set fsT = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        fsT.Mode = adModeRead
        fsT.Type = 2 'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
        fsT.Charset = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data.
        fsT.Open 'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
        fsT.LoadFromFile (sPath)
        ReadTextFile = fsT.ReadText
        fsT.Close
        Set fsT = Nothing
    Else
        ReadTextFile = ""
    End If
End Function


Public Function WriteTextFile(ByVal s As String, ByVal sPath As String) As Boolean
    Dim objStreamUTF8NoBOM: Set objStreamUTF8NoBOM = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    
    Dim fsT As Object
    Set fsT = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    fsT.Type = 2 'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
    fsT.Charset = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data.
    fsT.Open 'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
    fsT.WriteText s
    fsT.Position = 0
    fsT.SaveToFile sPath, 2 'Save binary data To disk
    fsT.Position = 3
    
    With objStreamUTF8NoBOM
      .Type = 1
      .Open
      fsT.CopyTo objStreamUTF8NoBOM
      .SaveToFile sPath, 2
      Close
    End With
    
    fsT.Close
    Set fsT = Nothing
    Set objStreamUTF8NoBOM = Nothing

End Function

Function SetSettings(ByVal Keyname As String, ByVal Wstr As String) As String
    Dim settingsFileContent
    settingsFileContent = ReadTextFile(IniFileName)
    
    Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RE.Pattern = Keyname + "=.*"
    RE.MultiLine = 1
    
    If RE.Test(settingsFileContent) Then
        settingsFileContent = RE.Replace(settingsFileContent, Keyname + "=" + Wstr)
    Else
        settingsFileContent = settingsFileContent + IIf(Len(settingsFileContent) = 0, "", vbNewLine) + Keyname + "=" + Wstr
    End If
    
    WriteTextFile settingsFileContent, IniFileName
    SetSettings = Wstr
End Function

Private Function GetSettings(ByVal Keyname As String) As String
    Dim settingsFileContent As String
    settingsFileContent = ReadTextFile(IniFileName)
    
    Set RE = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RE.MultiLine = 1
    RE.Global = 1
    RE.Pattern = "\r"
    settingsFileContent = RE.Replace(settingsFileContent, "")
    
    RE.Global = 0
    RE.Pattern = "^" + Keyname + "=(.*)"
    Set allMatches = RE.Execute(settingsFileContent)
    
    If allMatches.Count <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print (Keyname + ": """ + allMatches.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0) + """")
        GetSettings = allMatches.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0)
    Else
        GetSettings = ""
    End If
End Function
```