# Appending 2 CSV files, but produces garbage characters

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a VB Excel Macro code that will help me to append 2 CSV files, but the problem is, the old CSV contains some **Japanese texts**, so after running through the code / script, the new CSV file contains **garbage texts**

Can anyone kindly help me or point out what's wrong with my code?

```
Sub Append2CSV()
    Dim tmpCSV As String 'string to hold the CSV info
    Dim f As Integer
    Dim csvFile As String
    Set data_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
   
    LastColumnCell = data_sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    csvFile = Range("E3").Value
    f = FreeFile
    
    Open csvFile For Append As #f
        tmpCSV = Range2CSV(Range("A5:CZ" & LastColumnCell))
    Print #f, tmpCSV
    Close #f
    
    MsgBox "Test Data is appended in the Static Resource succesfully.", vbOKOnly, "Static Resource Update"
    
End Sub

Function Range2CSV(list As Range) As String
    
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim csvRecord As String, csvEmptyFields As String
    Dim csvAll As String
    
    csvAll = ""
    
    data = list.Value
    For r = 1 To UBound(data)
        csvEmptyFields = ""
        csvRecord = ""
        For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
            If Not IsEmpty(data(r, c)) Then
                csvRecord = csvRecord & csvEmptyFields & data(r, c) & ","
                csvEmptyFields = ""
            Else
                csvEmptyFields = csvEmptyFields & ","
            End If
        Next
        If csvRecord <> "" Then csvAll = csvAll & Left(csvRecord, Len(csvRecord) - 1) & vbLf
    Next

    Range2CSV = Left(csvAll, Len(csvAll) - 1)
    
End Function
```

Sample Screenshots

[image]

red line: existing cases (not garbage) 
blue line: appended data (garbage)

I've tried the comment FsT is not working, and the Garbage data still appears

```
Open csvFile For Append As #f
        tmpCSV = Range2CSV(Range("A5:CZ" & LastColumnCell))
        
        On Error GoTo errHandler
        Dim fsT As Object
        Dim tFilePath As String
        tFilePath = csvFile + ".csv"
        
        Set fsT = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        fsT.Type = 2 'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
        fsT.Charset = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data.
        fsT.Open 'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
        fsT.WriteText tmpCSV
        fsT.SaveToFile tFilePath, 2 'Save binary data To disk
errHandler:
    Close #f
```

Comment: `Print` is an very old command and can handle only ASCII characters - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524703/save-text-file-utf-8-encoded-with-vba for alternatives

Comment: hey @PEH can you turn off this duplicate question tag? I found the right answer and it's not the above comment, what a rude way to block someone's question... I'll post my found correct solution this so I could help others too