# How do I prevent replacement characters after creating HTML file

Tags: html, excel, vba

Below will not make much sense, but is part of a bigger script.
The example below takes the contents of an HTML file, creates a new HTML file and overwrites the source HTML with the same contents

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
With IE
    .Navigate filePath
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
    Set HTMLdoc = .Document
End With

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FileToCreate = FSO.CreateTextFile(filePath)
FileToCreate.Write HTMLdoc.DocumentElement.outerHTML
```

I expected the output to be similar to the source HTML but for some reason, special characters are replaced with replacement characters `�`

Examples of replaced characters are: ë, °

**WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR**
Is there a way to prevent special characters to be replaced with replacement characters?

Comment: You could try to use the optional parameter _unicode_ of the [CreateTextFile-Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createtextfile-method)

Comment: Are this characters really replaced, or is your editor/viewer not capable to show them?

Comment: @Shrotter: Setting the Unicode Boolean to true, does indeed keep special characters, but seems to do more than that. formatting (css) is no longer applied and the file doubled in size.

Comment: @Shrotter: The viewer is capable of showing them. Before I run the code mentioned in my question it looks fine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524703/save-text-file-utf-8-encoded-with-vba ?

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 solutions to this problem:

**SOLUTION 1**
Thanks to the link provided by @QHarr I was able to solve this
This solution handles the special characters upon saving.

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
With IE
    .Navigate filePath
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
    Set HTMLdoc = .Document
End With


Dim fsT As Object
Set fsT = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
fsT.Type = 2 'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
fsT.Charset = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data.
fsT.Open 'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
fsT.WriteText HTMLdoc.DocumentElement.outerHTML
fsT.SaveToFile filePath, 2 'Save binary data To disk
```

[Save text file UTF-8 encoded with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524703/save-text-file-utf-8-encoded-with-vba)

**SOLUTION 2**
This solution uses MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 instead of the InternetExplorer.Application object (needs reference "Microsoft XML 6.0" in the VBA editor). This seems to handle special characters in a better way.

```
Dim IE As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set IE = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
IE.Open "GET", filePath, False
IE.send
While IE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend
Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLBody As MSHTML.HTMLBody
Set HTMLdoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set HTMLBody = HTMLdoc.body
HTMLBody.innerHTML = IE.responseText

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FileToCreate = FSO.CreateTextFile(filePath)
FileToCreate.Write HTMLdoc.DocumentElement.outerHTML
```