# Why is this VBA script corrupting files?

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-csv, automatic-semicolon-insertion

I've created a VBA script to save an xlsx file as a semi-colon-del CSV format, but unfortunately, it's corrupting the output/CSV file when it saves (in notebook I see only PK ). Can anyone give me insight as to why this is happening?

Specific use case:
I want to be able to download a file (features_AFX.csv) from FTP that is semi-colon delimited, import into Excel using Power Query Editor (to retain special characters in the transformation), make edits, and then save/output as semi-colon delimited.  Changing my regional settings to use semi-colon as the default delimiter is not practical as I usually work with commas as the delimiter and only need semi-colons for a few files.  Additionally, I wanted to make sure the special characters within cells (which could also include semi-colons) were retained when exporting to csv.

- Note: all files are saved in filepath C:\Users\Julie

VBA script:

```
Private Sub commaReplace()

    Dim objFSO
    Dim filePath
    Dim migratorFileName
    Dim strFullPath1
    Dim strFullPath2
    Const ForReading = 1
    'define a TextStream object
    Dim objTS
    Dim strContents As String

    'note, my code actually uses the below commented out filepath
    'as the location of the workbook can be arbitrary, e.g.
    'Worksheets("FilePath").[A2:A2].Value is determined when workbook
    'is opened
    'filePath = Worksheets("FilePath").[A2:A2].Value
    filePath = "C:\Users\julie\"

    'our original file that we've exported as csv file in another section of code
    migratorFileName = "features_AFXMASTER.xlsx"
    strFullPath1 = filePath + migratorFileName

    'the path and file name we want to save to, semicolon separated vs. comma
    migratorFileName = "features_AFX.csv"
    strFullPath2 = filePath + migratorFileName

    'read everything from the csv file, replacing comma with semicolon
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFullPath1, ForReading)
    strContents = objTS.ReadAll
    strContents = Replace(strContents, ",", ";")
    objTS.Close

    'write everything out to another file, note, this could just overwrite
    'the original file if you pass the optional overwrite flag
    Set objTS = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFullPath2)
    objTS.Write strContents
    objTS.Close

End Sub
```

Thank you!!
Julie

Tried:

Attempt 1: Downloaded features_AFX.csv (already semi-colon delimited) to C:\Users\Julie.  Imported to Excel using Power Query Editor, and assigned file name features_AFXMASTER.xlsm.  Appended VBA script to features_AFXMASTER.xlsm and ran the script.  No error appeared and features_AFX file was updated, but on opening the file, it had been corrupted.

Attempt 2: Downloaded features_AFX.csv to C:\Users\Julie. Imported to Excel using Power Query Editor, and assigned file name features_AFXMASTER.xlsm. (file remained from Attempt 1 with VBA appended)  Deleted features_AFX.csv.  Ran VBA script in features_AFXMASTER.  No error appeared and features_AFX.csv file was created.  On opening the .csv, it was corrupted.

Attempt 3: Created a separate file named features_VBA.xlsm with VBA script appended.  Downloaded features_AFX.csv to C:\Users\Julie. Imported to Excel using Power Query Editor, and assigned file name features_AFXMASTER.xlsm. (this was a newly-created file, not leftover from previous attempts) Deleted features_AFX.csv.  Ran VBA script in features_VBA.  No error appeared and features_AFX.csv file was created.  On opening the .csv, it was corrupted.

Expected:

features_AFX.csv should be saved with semi-colons as the delimiter

Comment: `migratorFileName = "features_AFXMASTER.xlsx"` ... should that be a `.csv` file?

Comment: You could try using the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA to see if the code inspections flag up anything you are missing.  It may also be worth reveiwing regional settings to make sure that the output isn't being corrupted by . to , transposition in numbers (for example).

Comment: What exactly do you see in the "corrupted" files?  `Replace(strContents, ",", ";")` will also replace any commas contained in field values, and any existing fields which happen to already contain semicolons will not be quoted in your updated file, so those semicolons will appear as field separators when the file is re-opened.

Comment: @BigBen I wanted to import the csv and then save as xlsx to make necessary edits before exporting/resaving to csv.  The idea for the "AFXMASTER" file was to have a standing master version of the data that I would import into - but it's not a requirement.

Comment: @freeflow thanks for the suggestion - I'll look into Rubberduck.

Comment: @TimWilliams when I open in Notepad I see "P" followed by four squares.  If I open in Excel I see more, but it's all strange characters.  I knew it was a possibility that existing semi-colons in the file might appear as field separators - I was hoping to get the VBA script to work and then see if I could figure out how to manage that part.

Comment: Sounds like maybe also a codepage/character set problem. FSO  is not good for reading /writing (eg) UTF-8 or similar formats.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2525196/478884 shows how to write content to a UTF-8 encoded text file.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too tricky to export directly from Excel to a text file:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    PutContent "C:\Temp\test.csv", RangeToText(Selection, ";")
End Sub

'Create a string from the content of range `rng`, using `FieldSep`
'  to separate field values.  Quote any values containing `FieldSep`
Function RangeToText(rng As Range, FieldSep As String) As String
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, sep As String, content As String, v
    For r = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        sep = ""
        For c = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            v = rng.Cells(r, c).Value
            'quote any field values containing `FieldSep`
            If InStr(1, v, FieldSep, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                v = """" & v & """"
            End If
            content = content & sep & v
            sep = FieldSep 'populate after 1st value on the line
        Next c
        content = content & vbCrLf 'default Windows line separator
    Next r
    RangeToText = content
End Function

'Write text in `content` to a text file at path `f`
Sub PutContent(f As String, content As String)
    CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject"). _
                  OpenTextFile(f, 2, True).Write content
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: if you need to write to a UTF-8 encoded file then you can use:

```
Sub WriteUTF8(filePath As String, content As String)
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 2 'adTypeText: text/string data
        .Charset = "utf-8" 'default is "Unicode"
        .Open
        .WriteText content
        .SaveToFile filePath, 2 'Save to disk
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @timwillians - will give this a try, although it sounds like I may still have the problem with semicolons that are not intended as field separators.   Still, would be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need and made a .vbs to call that would mass change in a flat file one character to another.
It has three parameters

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
strFileName = Wscript.Arguments(0)
strOldText = Wscript.Arguments(1)
strNewText = Wscript.Arguments(2)
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForReading)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
newText = Replace(strText, strOldText, strNewText)
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine newText
objFile.Close
```

Created a small test file
'TestDoc.txt': Col1,col2,col3,col4
Opened CMD prompt (in the folder containing the script: 'RawMod.vbs' and test file and ran
rawmod.vbs "TestDoc.txt" "," "|"
TestDoc.txt was updated to: Col1|col2|col3|col4

Please let me know if this is useful

Comment: Thanks @jan - will also give this a try.